# Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose you have a dictionary like:

```
{'a': 1,
 'c': {'a': 2,
       'b': {'x': 5,
             'y' : 10}},
 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

How would you go about flattening that into something like:

```
{'a': 1,
 'c_a': 2,
 'c_b_x': 5,
 'c_b_y': 10,
 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: also, there is a library for it: https://github.com/ianlini/flatten-dict

Comment: **see also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690

Comment: I see very different performance for the approaches suggested in the answers.

Comment: The question should have at the end: "so that all levels' keys on the path to the leaf are concatenated?" Or change the header to "compressing (= concatenating) keys". There should be "concatenat" in the question for those who search. I was searching for a solution that would give a **list** of the keys on the path to the leaf, not a concatenation. You could say use `split()` then, but there are other direct ways that this question does not encourage.

Answer (score 335):

Basically the same way you would flatten a nested list, you just have to do the extra work for iterating the dict by key/value, creating new keys for your new dictionary and creating the dictionary at final step.

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def flatten(dictionary, parent_key='', separator='_'):
    items = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        new_key = parent_key + separator + key if parent_key else key
        if isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(value, new_key, separator=separator).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, value))
    return dict(items)

>>> flatten({'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]})
{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'd': [1, 2, 3], 'c_b_y': 10}
```

Comment: If you replace the `isinstance` with a `try..except` block, this will work for any mapping, even if it is not derived from `dict`.

Comment: Changed it to test for `collections.MutableMapping` to make it more generic. But for Python < 2.6, `try..except` is probably the best option.

Comment: If you want empty dictionaries preserved in flattened version you might want to change `if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):` to `if v and isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):`

Comment: exactly what i wanted... thanks!!! remember to import collections when using this.

Comment: Note that `new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k` assumes that keys are always strings, otherwise it will raise `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and [other] objects`. However, you could fix that by simply coercing `k` to string (`str(k)`), or concatenating keys into a tuple instead of a string (tuples can be dict keys, too).

Comment: And the inflate function is [here](https://gist.github.com/fmder/494aaa2dd6f8c428cede)

Comment: That is cool. I was looking for a way to have a program reference a dict, like a xpath, this worked great!

Comment: You can replace `items = []; ... return dict(items)` with `result = {}; ... return result`. This will work slightly faster.

Comment: What if I want to flatten an array and objects inside it? This is not working for arrays. For eg. `{'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}` should give me `{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'd_0': 1, 'd_1': 2,'d_2': 3, 'c_b_y': 10}`

Comment: Answered my own query: I added one "elif" and that did the trick... `elif isinstance(v,list):
                for idx,val in enumerate(v):
                    new_key = str(parent_key) + sep + str(k) + sep + str(idx) if parent_key else str(k) + sep + str(idx)
                    items.extend(Controller.flatten(v[idx],new_key,sep=sep).items())`

Comment: If using Python 3.5+, the dictionary unpacking seems to be [the fastest](https://gist.github.com/treyhunner/f35292e676efa0be1728), so do `items = {**items, **flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep)}`

Comment: im new using collections, but what does collections.MutableMapping do? Ive looked online and cant find a good explanation

Comment: I created a dictionary like this similar to a case i had but this failed to run successfully on it . 
my_dict=xmltodict.parse("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><A V1="X1"><B><B1><V2>X2</V2><V3>X3</V3><V4>X4</V4><V5>X5</V5><V6>X6</V6></B1><C><D><V7>X7</V7><V8>X8</V8><E><V10>X10</V10><V9>X9</V9><V11>X11</V11><V12>X12</V12></E></D></C></B></A>""")

The answered code doesnot work for this

Comment: Actually these do not work for xml with repeating tags or sub-tree it seems.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in C++? Which data structure would hold the input?

Comment: @Maddy using boost property tree might help, check that.

Comment: If you have integers as key, you need to change `k` to `str(k)`, else you get `in flatten(d, parent_key, sep)
      4     items = []
      5     for k, v in d.items():
----> 6         new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
      7         if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
      8             items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to test for instances of `Mapping` instead of `MutableMapping` even though the standard library still lacks an frozenmap type, you may still come across user types that devive from `Mapping`.

Comment: @roneo What happens in the ```if parent_key```statement?

Comment: @RSale Default boolean comparison (e.g. bool("") -> False, etc.)
It's a somewhat "hacky" way to simulate `?:˙ C operator

Comment: If anyone wants to get list of only the keys. Here's my version inspired from this. https://gist.github.com/AmitChotaliya/3a1f1181c5d2ef7260432a8112e440de

Answer (score 216):

If you are already using pandas, you can do it with [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) like so:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': 1,
     'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}},
     'd': [1, 2, 3]}

df = pd.json_normalize(d, sep='_')
d_flat = df.to_dict(orient='records')[0]

print(d_flat)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'c_b_y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Bit of a shame it doesn't handle lists :)

Comment: In my application, the pandas approach really dragged down performance compared to @imran's answer

Comment: This does not work if you have integers as keys in the dictionary: `98                 if level != 0:  # so we skip copying for top level, common case
---> 99                     v = new_d.pop(k)
    100                     new_d[newkey] = v
    101                 continue

KeyError: '6'`

Comment: @MohammadYusuf I could not convert keys to string using just a parameter in the `json_normalize` function. It is built-in on the JSON side. Perhaps, they will change it in future. It still is a compact one-liner and good for the standard case of string keys.

Answer (score 81):

There are two big considerations that the original poster needs to consider:

1. Are there keyspace clobbering issues? For example, `{'a_b':{'c':1}, 'a':{'b_c':2}}` would result in `{'a_b_c':???}`. The below solution evades the problem by returning an iterable of pairs.
2. If performance is an issue, does the key-reducer function (which I hereby refer to as 'join') require access to the entire key-path, or can it just do O(1) work at every node in the tree? If you want to be able to say `joinedKey = '_'.join(*keys)`, that will cost you O(N^2) running time. However if you're willing to say `nextKey = previousKey+'_'+thisKey`, that gets you O(N) time. The solution below lets you do both (since you could merely concatenate all the keys, then postprocess them).

(Performance is not likely an issue, but I'll elaborate on the second point in case anyone else cares: In implementing this, there are numerous dangerous choices. If you do this recursively and yield and re-yield, or *anything* equivalent which touches nodes more than once (which is quite easy to accidentally do), you are doing potentially O(N^2) work rather than O(N). This is because maybe you are calculating a key `a` then `a_1` then `a_1_i`..., and then calculating `a` then `a_1` then `a_1_ii`..., but really you shouldn't have to calculate `a_1` again. Even if you aren't recalculating it, re-yielding it (a 'level-by-level' approach) is just as bad. A good example is to think about the performance on `{1:{1:{1:{1:...(N times)...{1:SOME_LARGE_DICTIONARY_OF_SIZE_N}...}}}}`)

Below is a function I wrote `flattenDict(d, join=..., lift=...)` which can be adapted to many purposes and can do what you want. Sadly it is fairly hard to make a lazy version of this function without incurring the above performance penalties (many python builtins like chain.from_iterable aren't actually efficient, which I only realized after extensive testing of three different versions of this code before settling on this one).

```
from collections import Mapping
from itertools import chain
from operator import add

_FLAG_FIRST = object()

def flattenDict(d, join=add, lift=lambda x:(x,)):
    results = []
    def visit(subdict, results, partialKey):
        for k,v in subdict.items():
            newKey = lift(k) if partialKey==_FLAG_FIRST else join(partialKey,lift(k))
            if isinstance(v,Mapping):
                visit(v, results, newKey)
            else:
                results.append((newKey,v))
    visit(d, results, _FLAG_FIRST)
    return results
```

To better understand what's going on, below is a diagram for those unfamiliar with `reduce`(left), otherwise known as "fold left". Sometimes it is drawn with an initial value in place of k0 (not part of the list, passed into the function). Here, `J` is our `join` function. We preprocess each k<sub>n</sub> with `lift(k)`.

```
               [k0,k1,...,kN].foldleft(J)
                           /    \
                         ...    kN
                         /
       J(k0,J(k1,J(k2,k3)))
                       /  \
                      /    \
           J(J(k0,k1),k2)   k3
                    /   \
                   /     \
             J(k0,k1)    k2
                 /  \
                /    \
               k0     k1
```

This is in fact the same as `functools.reduce`, but where our function does this to all key-paths of the tree.

```
>>> reduce(lambda a,b:(a,b), range(5))
((((0, 1), 2), 3), 4)
```

Demonstration (which I'd otherwise put in docstring):

```
>>> testData = {
        'a':1,
        'b':2,
        'c':{
            'aa':11,
            'bb':22,
            'cc':{
                'aaa':111
            }
        }
    }
from pprint import pprint as pp

>>> pp(dict( flattenDict(testData) ))
{('a',): 1,
 ('b',): 2,
 ('c', 'aa'): 11,
 ('c', 'bb'): 22,
 ('c', 'cc', 'aaa'): 111}

>>> pp(dict( flattenDict(testData, join=lambda a,b:a+'_'+b, lift=lambda x:x) ))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c_aa': 11, 'c_bb': 22, 'c_cc_aaa': 111}    

>>> pp(dict( (v,k) for k,v in flattenDict(testData, lift=hash, join=lambda a,b:hash((a,b))) ))
{1: 12416037344,
 2: 12544037731,
 11: 5470935132935744593,
 22: 4885734186131977315,
 111: 3461911260025554326}
```

---

Performance:

```
from functools import reduce
def makeEvilDict(n):
    return reduce(lambda acc,x:{x:acc}, [{i:0 for i in range(n)}]+range(n))

import timeit
def time(runnable):
    t0 = timeit.default_timer()
    _ = runnable()
    t1 = timeit.default_timer()
    print('took {:.2f} seconds'.format(t1-t0))

>>> pp(makeEvilDict(8))
{7: {6: {5: {4: {3: {2: {1: {0: {0: 0,
                                 1: 0,
                                 2: 0,
                                 3: 0,
                                 4: 0,
                                 5: 0,
                                 6: 0,
                                 7: 0}}}}}}}}}

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)

forget = lambda a,b:''

>>> time(lambda: dict(flattenDict(makeEvilDict(10000), join=forget)) )
took 0.10 seconds
>>> time(lambda: dict(flattenDict(makeEvilDict(100000), join=forget)) )
[1]    12569 segmentation fault  python
```

... sigh, don't think that one is my fault...

---

[unimportant historical note due to moderation issues]

**Regarding the alleged duplicate of [Flatten a dictionary of dictionaries (2 levels deep) of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835192/sum-or-map-over-all-values-of-nested-dictionaries-in-python:)**

That question's solution can be implemented in terms of this one by doing `sorted( sum(flatten(...),[]) )`. The reverse is not possible: while it is true that the **values** of `flatten(...)` can be recovered from the alleged duplicate by mapping a higher-order accumulator, one cannot recover the keys. (edit: Also it turns out that the alleged duplicate owner's question is completely different, in that it only deals with dictionaries exactly 2-level deep, though one of the answers on that page gives a general solution.)

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant to the question. This solution does not flatten a dictionary item of a list of dictionaries, i.e. {'a': [{'aa': 1}, {'ab': 2}]}. The flattenDict function can be altered easily to accommodate this case.

Comment: Use `join(partialKey + '_',lift(k)` if you need the underscores as in the question.

Comment: If you have integers as keys in the dictionary, you need to change `lift(k)` to `str(lift(k))` to avoid `in visit(subdict, results, partialKey)
      9     def visit(subdict, results, partialKey):
     10         for k,v in subdict.items():
---> 11             newKey = lift(k) if partialKey==_FLAG_FIRST else join(partialKey + ',',lift(k))
     12             if isinstance(v,Mapping):
     13                 visit(v, results, newKey)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`.

Comment: @questionto42: There is no change necessary; that is the purpose of the `lift` parameter. You can just set `flattenDict(..., join=lambda a,b:a+'_'+b, lift=repr)` (or `str` but that's not a good idea due to key collsions 1<->'1') rather than leaving lift as the identity function and modifying the general-purpose code.

Comment: Now that looks like higher science :) I see your point with the collisions, though.

Answer (score 52):

If you're using `pandas` there is a function hidden in `pandas.io.json._normalize`<sup>1</sup> called `nested_to_record` which does this exactly.

```
from pandas.io.json._normalize import nested_to_record    

flat = nested_to_record(my_dict, sep='_')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In pandas versions `0.24.x` and older use `pandas.io.json.normalize` (without the `_`)

Comment: What worked for me was `from pandas.io.json._normalize import nested_to_record`. Notice the underscore (`_`) before `normalize`.

Comment: @EyalLevin Good catch!  This changed in `0.25.x`, I've updated the answer. :)

Comment: This does not work if you have integers as keys in the dictionary. `--> 103                 v = new_d.pop(k)
    104                 new_d.update(nested_to_record(v, newkey, sep, level + 1, max_level))
    105         new_ds.append(new_d)

KeyError: '6'`

Answer (score 40):

Not exactly what the OP asked, but lots of folks are coming here looking for ways to flatten real-world nested JSON data which can have nested key-value json objects and arrays and json objects inside the arrays and so on. JSON doesn't include tuples, so we don't have to fret over those.

I found an implementation of the list-inclusion [comment by @roneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys#comment99288620_6027615) to the [answer posted by @Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027615/4355695) :

https://github.com/ScriptSmith/socialreaper/blob/master/socialreaper/tools.py#L8

```
import collections
def flatten(dictionary, parent_key=False, separator='.'):
    """
    Turn a nested dictionary into a flattened dictionary
    :param dictionary: The dictionary to flatten
    :param parent_key: The string to prepend to dictionary's keys
    :param separator: The string used to separate flattened keys
    :return: A flattened dictionary
    """

    items = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        new_key = str(parent_key) + separator + key if parent_key else key
        if isinstance(value, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(value, new_key, separator).items())
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for k, v in enumerate(value):
                items.extend(flatten({str(k): v}, new_key).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, value))
    return dict(items)
```

Test it:

```
flatten({'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3] })

>> {'a': 1, 'c.a': 2, 'c.b.x': 5, 'c.b.y': 10, 'd.0': 1, 'd.1': 2, 'd.2': 3}
```

Annd that does the job I need done: I throw any complicated json at this and it flattens it out for me.

All credits to https://github.com/ScriptSmith .

#### 2023-06-14 Update for python >= 3.10

Since Python 3.10, `collections.MutableMapping` has changed to `collections.abc.MutableMapping`. Hence code above is edited to reflect the same. If your python version is before 3.10, please change it back to `collections.MutableMapping` at your side.
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902541/4355695

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far since it handles nested lists of dicts.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is best one, as it works with lists as well.

Comment: In case: any comes across an error: `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'`

Use, `from collections.abc import MutableMapping`.  `collections.MutableMapping` has been deprecated.

Comment: what about creating multiple rows of data

Comment: @geekidharsh didn't get you.. if you're referring to a list of nested dicts you want to flatten, then: assuming `data` holds the list.. `data_flat = [flatten(row) for row in data]`

Answer (score 39):

Here is a kind of a "functional", "one-liner" implementation. It is recursive, and based on a conditional expression and a dict comprehension.

```
def flatten_dict(dd, separator='_', prefix=''):
    return { prefix + separator + k if prefix else k : v
             for kk, vv in dd.items()
             for k, v in flatten_dict(vv, separator, kk).items()
             } if isinstance(dd, dict) else { prefix : dd }
```

Test:

```
In [2]: flatten_dict({'abc':123, 'hgf':{'gh':432, 'yu':433}, 'gfd':902, 'xzxzxz':{"432":{'0b0b0b':231}, "43234":1321}}, '.')
Out[2]: 
{'abc': 123,
 'gfd': 902,
 'hgf.gh': 432,
 'hgf.yu': 433,
 'xzxzxz.432.0b0b0b': 231,
 'xzxzxz.43234': 1321}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for general dictionaries, specifically, with tuple keys, eg substitute `('hgf',2)` for the 2nd key in your test throws `TypeError`

Comment: @alancalvitti This assumes it to be a string, or something else that supports the `+` operator. For anything else you'll need to adapt `prefix + separator + k` to the appropriate function call to compose the objects.

Comment: Another issue relevant to tuple keys. I've posted separately how to generalize based on your method. However it cannot correctly handle ninjageko's example: `{'a_b':{'c':1}, 'a':{'b_c':2}}`

Comment: I was getting worried, seeing no answers utilizing recursion. What's wrong with our youth these days?

Comment: does nothing if a dict has nested list of dicts, like this: `{'name': 'Steven', 'children': [{'name': 'Jessica', 'children': []}, {'name': 'George', 'children': []}]}`

Comment: @GergelyM during traversal we fundamentally assume that a value is either a dict, and therefore a node to be visited iterating over the keys, or a leaf otherwise. A list is just taken to be a non-traversable value. You probably need to adapt the algorithm to your application here, depending on what you need. What should even be the output here, and how does it relate to the OP question?

Comment: Sure, not trying to question a good solution and you're absolutely correct - if we're taking granted the input dictionary contains only dictionaries. Though, it's more life-like and completely valid for a python dictionary to store other data-structures, a list of dictionaries for example.

Comment: If you have an integer in the keys, you need `str(k)` and `str(kk)`.

Comment: @Jakov: The top answers are recursive, and if you take the "json" trick as inherently recursive, all of the higher voted answers are recursive.

Answer (score 17):

Code:

```
test = {'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}

def parse_dict(init, lkey=''):
    ret = {}
    for rkey,val in init.items():
        key = lkey+rkey
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            ret.update(parse_dict(val, key+'_'))
        else:
            ret[key] = val
    return ret

print(parse_dict(test,''))
```

Results:

```
$ python test.py
{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'd': [1, 2, 3], 'c_b_y': 10}
```

I am using python3.2, update for your version of python.

Comment: You probably want to specify the default value of `lkey=''` in your function definition instead of when calling the function. See other answers in this regard.

Answer (score 8):

This is not restricted to dictionaries, but every mapping type that implements .items(). Further ist faster as it avoides an if condition. Nevertheless credits go to Imran:

```
def flatten(d, parent_key=''):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            items.extend(flatten(v, '%s%s_' % (parent_key, k)).items())
        except AttributeError:
            items.append(('%s%s' % (parent_key, k), v))
    return dict(items)
```

Comment: If `d` is not a `dict` but a custom mapping type that doesn't implement `items`, your function would fail right then and there. So, it it does not work for every mapping type but only those that implement `items()`.

Comment: @user6037143 have you ever encountered a mapping type that doesn't implement `items`? I'd be curious to see one.

Comment: @user6037143, no you haven't by definition if items is not implemented it's no mapping type.

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad, could you modify this to handle general keys eg tuples which should not be internally flattened.

Answer (score 7):

How about a *functional* and performant solution in Python3.5?

```
from functools import reduce


def _reducer(items, key, val, pref):
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        return {**items, **flatten(val, pref + key)}
    else:
        return {**items, pref + key: val}

def flatten(d, pref=''):
    return(reduce(
        lambda new_d, kv: _reducer(new_d, *kv, pref), 
        d.items(), 
        {}
    ))
```

This is even more performant:

```
def flatten(d, pref=''):
    return(reduce(
        lambda new_d, kv: \
            isinstance(kv[1], dict) and \
            {**new_d, **flatten(kv[1], pref + kv[0])} or \
            {**new_d, pref + kv[0]: kv[1]}, 
        d.items(), 
        {}
    ))
```

In use:

```
my_obj = {'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y': 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}

print(flatten(my_obj)) 
# {'d': [1, 2, 3], 'cby': 10, 'cbx': 5, 'ca': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: How about a readable and working solution? ;) Which version did you test this on? I'm Getting "Syntax error" when trying this out in  Python 3.4.3. Seems that usage of  "**all" is not legit.

Comment: I works since Python 3.5. Didn't know it doesn't work with 3.4. You're right this isn't very readable. I updated the answer. Hope it's more readable now. :)

Comment: Added missing reduce import. Still find the code hard to understand and I think it's a good example why Guido van Rossum himself discouraged the usage of lambda, reduce, filter and map in 2005 already: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: I agree. Python isn't really designed for *functional programming*. Still I think `reduce` is great in case you need to reduce dictionaries. I updated the answer. Should look a little more pythonic now.

Answer (score 7):

If you are a fan of **pythonic oneliners**:

```
my_dict={'a': 1,'c': {'a': 2,'b': {'x': 5,'y' : 10}},'d': [1, 2, 3]}

list(pd.json_normalize(my_dict).T.to_dict().values())[0]
```

returns:

```
{'a': 1, 'c.a': 2, 'c.b.x': 5, 'c.b.y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

You can leave the `[0]` from the end, if you have a list of dictionaries and not just a single dictionary.

Comment: It can be a one liner, but the cost of this operation is exaggerate in terms of performance.

Comment: 300-400 times slower than the fastest solution of all posted approaches here.

Answer (score 6):

My Python 3.3 Solution using generators:

```
def flattenit(pyobj, keystring=''):
   if type(pyobj) is dict:
     if (type(pyobj) is dict):
         keystring = keystring + "_" if keystring else keystring
         for k in pyobj:
             yield from flattenit(pyobj[k], keystring + k)
     elif (type(pyobj) is list):
         for lelm in pyobj:
             yield from flatten(lelm, keystring)
   else:
      yield keystring, pyobj

my_obj = {'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y': 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}

#your flattened dictionary object
flattened={k:v for k,v in flattenit(my_obj)}
print(flattened)

# result: {'c_b_y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3], 'c_a': 2, 'a': 1, 'c_b_x': 5}
```

Comment: can you extend to handle any valid key type other than str (including tuple)? Instead of string concatenation, join them in a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

Utilizing recursion, keeping it simple and human readable:

```
def flatten_dict(dictionary, accumulator=None, parent_key=None, separator="."):
    if accumulator is None:
        accumulator = {}

    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        k = f"{parent_key}{separator}{k}" if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_dict(dictionary=v, accumulator=accumulator, parent_key=k)
            continue

        accumulator[k] = v

    return accumulator
```

Call is simple:

```
new_dict = flatten_dict(dictionary)
```

or

```
new_dict = flatten_dict(dictionary, separator="_")
```

if we want to change the default separator.

**A little breakdown:**

When the function is first called, it is called only passing the `dictionary` we want to flatten. The `accumulator` parameter is here to support recursion, which we see later. So, we instantiate `accumulator` to an empty dictionary where we will put all of the nested values from the original `dictionary`.

```
if accumulator is None:
    accumulator = {}
```

As we iterate over the dictionary's values, we construct a key for every value. The `parent_key` argument will be `None` for the first call, while for every nested dictionary, it will contain the key pointing to it, so we prepend that key.

```
k = f"{parent_key}{separator}{k}" if parent_key else k
```

In case the value `v` the key `k` is pointing to is a dictionary, the function calls itself, passing the nested dictionary, the `accumulator` (which is passed by reference, so all changes done to it are done on the same instance) and the key `k` so that we can construct the concatenated key. Notice the `continue` statement. We want to skip the next line, outside of the `if` block, so that the nested dictionary doesn't end up in the `accumulator` under key `k`.

```
if isinstance(v, dict):
    flatten_dict(dict=v, accumulator=accumulator, parent_key=k)
    continue
```

So, what do we do in case the value `v` is not a dictionary? Just put it unchanged inside the `accumulator`.

```
accumulator[k] = v
```

Once we're done we just return the `accumulator`, leaving the original `dictionary` argument untouched.

**NOTE**

This will work only with dictionaries that have strings as keys. It will work with hashable objects implementing the `__repr__` method, but will yield unwanted results.

Answer (score 5):

here's a solution using a stack. No recursion.

```
def flatten_nested_dict(nested):
    stack = list(nested.items())
    ans = {}
    while stack:
        key, val = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for sub_key, sub_val in val.items():
                stack.append((f"{key}_{sub_key}", sub_val))
        else:
            ans[key] = val
    return ans
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple function to flatten nested dictionaries. For Python 3, replace `.iteritems()` with `.items()`

```
def flatten_dict(init_dict):
    res_dict = {}
    if type(init_dict) is not dict:
        return res_dict

    for k, v in init_dict.iteritems():
        if type(v) == dict:
            res_dict.update(flatten_dict(v))
        else:
            res_dict[k] = v

    return res_dict
```

The idea/requirement was:
Get flat dictionaries with no keeping parent keys.

Example of usage:

```
dd = {'a': 3, 
      'b': {'c': 4, 'd': 5}, 
      'e': {'f': 
                 {'g': 1, 'h': 2}
           }, 
      'i': 9,
     }

flatten_dict(dd)

>> {'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5, 'g': 1, 'h': 2, 'i': 9}
```

Keeping parent keys is simple as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking of a subclass of UserDict to automagically flat the keys.

```
class FlatDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, separator='.', **kwargs):
        self.separator = separator
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for k1, v1 in FlatDict(value, separator=self.separator).items():
                super().__setitem__(f"{key}{self.separator}{k1}", v1)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

‌
The advantages it that keys can be added on the fly, or using standard dict instanciation, without surprise:

‌

```
>>> fd = FlatDict(
...    {
...        'person': {
...            'sexe': 'male', 
...            'name': {
...                'first': 'jacques',
...                'last': 'dupond'
...            }
...        }
...    }
... )
>>> fd
{'person.sexe': 'male', 'person.name.first': 'jacques', 'person.name.last': 'dupond'}
>>> fd['person'] = {'name': {'nickname': 'Bob'}}
>>> fd
{'person.sexe': 'male', 'person.name.first': 'jacques', 'person.name.last': 'dupond', 'person.name.nickname': 'Bob'}
>>> fd['person.name'] = {'civility': 'Dr'}
>>> fd
{'person.sexe': 'male', 'person.name.first': 'jacques', 'person.name.last': 'dupond', 'person.name.nickname': 'Bob', 'person.name.civility': 'Dr'}
```

Comment: Assigning to fd['person'] but maintaining its existing value is quite surprising. That's not how regular dicts work.

Answer (score 3):

Using generators:

```
def flat_dic_helper(prepand,d):
    if len(prepand) > 0:
        prepand = prepand + "_"
    for k in d:
        i = d[k]
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            r = flat_dic_helper(prepand + k,i)
            for j in r:
                yield j
        else:
            yield (prepand + k,i)

def flat_dic(d):
    return dict(flat_dic_helper("",d))

d = {'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
print(flat_dic(d))


>> {'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'd': [1, 2, 3], 'c_b_y': 10}
```

Comment: `type(i).__name__=='dict'` could be replaced with `type(i) is dict` or perhaps even better `isinstance(d, dict)` (or `Mapping`/`MutableMapping`).

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to both imran's and ralu's answer. It does not use a generator, but instead employs recursion with a closure:

```
def flatten_dict(d, separator='_'):
  final = {}
  def _flatten_dict(obj, parent_keys=[]):
    for k, v in obj.iteritems():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
        _flatten_dict(v, parent_keys + [k])
      else:
        key = separator.join(parent_keys + [k])
        final[key] = v
  _flatten_dict(d)
  return final

>>> print flatten_dict({'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]})
{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'd': [1, 2, 3], 'c_b_y': 10}
```

Comment: I am not sure if using the term "[closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))" is correct here, as the function `_flatten_dict` is never returned, nor is it expected to ever be returned. It can perhaps be referred to as a _subfunction_ or an _enclosed function_ instead.

Answer (score 3):

The answers above work really well. Just thought I'd add the unflatten function that I wrote:

```
def unflatten(d):
    ud = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        context = ud
        for sub_key in k.split('_')[:-1]:
            if sub_key not in context:
                context[sub_key] = {}
            context = context[sub_key]
        context[k.split('_')[-1]] = v
    return ud
```

Note: This doesn't account for '_' already present in keys, much like the flatten counterparts.

Answer (score 3):

Davoud's solution is very nice but doesn't give satisfactory results when the nested dict also contains lists of dicts, but his code be adapted for that case:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            if (type(v)==type([])): 
                for l in v: items.extend(flatten_dict(l).items())
            else: 
                items.extend(flatten_dict(v).items())
        except AttributeError:
            items.append((k, v))
    return dict(items)
```

Comment: You could cache the result of `type([])` to avoid a function call for every item of the `dict`.

Comment: Please use `isinstance(v, list)` instead

Answer (score 3):

```
def flatten(unflattened_dict, separator='_'):
    flattened_dict = {}

    for k, v in unflattened_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sub_flattened_dict = flatten(v, separator)
            for k2, v2 in sub_flattened_dict.items():
                flattened_dict[k + separator + k2] = v2
        else:
            flattened_dict[k] = v

    return flattened_dict
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually wrote a package called cherrypicker recently to deal with this exact sort of thing since I had to do it so often!

I think the following code would give you exactly what you're after:

```
from cherrypicker import CherryPicker

dct = {
    'a': 1,
    'c': {
        'a': 2,
        'b': {
            'x': 5,
            'y' : 10
        }
    },
    'd': [1, 2, 3]
}

picker = CherryPicker(dct)
picker.flatten().get()
```

You can install the package with:

```
pip install cherrypicker
```

...and there's more docs and guidance at https://cherrypicker.readthedocs.io.

Other methods may be faster, but the priority of this package is to make such tasks *easy*. If you do have a large list of objects to flatten though, you can also tell CherryPicker to use parallel processing to speed things up.

Comment: I like the alternative approach.

Answer (score 3):

Using flatdict library:

```
dic={'a': 1,
 'c': {'a': 2,
       'b': {'x': 5,
             'y' : 10}},
 'd': [1, 2, 3]}

import flatdict
f =  flatdict.FlatDict(dic,delimiter='_')
print(f)
#output
{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'c_b_y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm for elegant, in-place replacement. Tested with Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. Using the dot character as a separator.

```
def flatten_json(json):
    if type(json) == dict:
        for k, v in list(json.items()):
            if type(v) == dict:
                flatten_json(v)
                json.pop(k)
                for k2, v2 in v.items():
                    json[k+"."+k2] = v2
```

Example:

```
d = {'a': {'b': 'c'}}                   
flatten_json(d)
print(d)
unflatten_json(d)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a.b': 'c'}
{'a': {'b': 'c'}}
```

I published this code [here](https://gist.github.com/aryzhov/067ecc12d39715217d787896a34915c6) along with the matching `unflatten_json` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to flat nested dictionary and want all unique keys list then here is the solution:

```
def flat_dict_return_unique_key(data, unique_keys=set()):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        [unique_keys.add(i) for i in data.keys()]
        for each_v in data.values():
            if isinstance(each_v, dict):
                flat_dict_return_unique_key(each_v, unique_keys)
    return list(set(unique_keys))
```

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer access `dict` objects via `.items()`, so for flattening dicts I use the following recursive generator `flat_items(d)`. If you like to have `dict` again, simply wrap it like this: `flat = dict(flat_items(d))`

```py
def flat_items(d, key_separator='.'):
    """
    Flattens the dictionary containing other dictionaries like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys

    >>> example = {'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
    >>> flat = dict(flat_items(example, key_separator='_'))
    >>> assert flat['c_b_y'] == 10
    """
    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) is dict:
            for k1, v1 in flat_items(v, key_separator=key_separator):
                yield key_separator.join((k, k1)), v1
        else:
            yield k, v
```

Comment: That's the best functional solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
def flatten_nested_dict(_dict, _str=''):
    '''
    recursive function to flatten a nested dictionary json
    '''
    ret_dict = {}
    for k, v in _dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            ret_dict.update(flatten_nested_dict(v, _str = '_'.join([_str, k]).strip('_')))
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for index, item in enumerate(v):
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    ret_dict.update(flatten_nested_dict(item,  _str= '_'.join([_str, k, str(index)]).strip('_')))
                else:
                    ret_dict['_'.join([_str, k, str(index)]).strip('_')] = item
        else:
            ret_dict['_'.join([_str, k]).strip('_')] = v
    return ret_dict
```

Comment: this works with lists inside our nested dict, but doesn't have a custom separator option

Answer (score 1):

Using dict.popitem() in straightforward nested-list-like recursion:

```
def flatten(d):
    if d == {}:
        return d
    else:
        k,v = d.popitem()
        if (dict != type(v)):
            return {k:v, **flatten(d)}
        else:
            flat_kv = flatten(v)
            for k1 in list(flat_kv.keys()):
                flat_kv[k + '_' + k1] = flat_kv[k1]
                del flat_kv[k1]
            return {**flat_kv, **flatten(d)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind recursive functions, here is a solution. I have also taken the liberty to include an *exclusion*-parameter in case there are one or more values you wish to maintain.

Code:

```
def flatten_dict(dictionary, exclude = [], delimiter ='_'):
    flat_dict = dict()
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict) and key not in exclude:
            flatten_value_dict = flatten_dict(value, exclude, delimiter)
            for k, v in flatten_value_dict.items():
                flat_dict[f"{key}{delimiter}{k}"] = v
        else:
            flat_dict[key] = value
    return flat_dict
```

Usage:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':[1, 2], 'c':3, 'd':{'a':4, 'b':{'a':7, 'b':8}, 'c':6}, 'e':{'a':1,'b':2}}
flat_d = flatten_dict(dictionary=d, exclude=['e'], delimiter='.')
print(flat_d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': 3, 'd.a': 4, 'd.b.a': 7, 'd.b.b': 8, 'd.c': 6, 'e': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of the solutions on this page - though not all - but those I tried failed to handle the nested list of dict.

Consider a dict like this:

```py
d = {
        'owner': {
            'name': {'first_name': 'Steven', 'last_name': 'Smith'},
            'lottery_nums': [1, 2, 3, 'four', '11', None],
            'address': {},
            'tuple': (1, 2, 'three'),
            'tuple_with_dict': (1, 2, 'three', {'is_valid': False}),
            'set': {1, 2, 3, 4, 'five'},
            'children': [
                {'name': {'first_name': 'Jessica',
                          'last_name': 'Smith', },
                 'children': []
                 },
                {'name': {'first_name': 'George',
                          'last_name': 'Smith'},
                 'children': []
                 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Here's my makeshift solution:

```py
def flatten_dict(input_node: dict, key_: str = '', output_dict: dict = {}):
    if isinstance(input_node, dict):
        for key, val in input_node.items():
            new_key = f"{key_}.{key}" if key_ else f"{key}"
            flatten_dict(val, new_key, output_dict)
    elif isinstance(input_node, list):
        for idx, item in enumerate(input_node):
            flatten_dict(item, f"{key_}.{idx}", output_dict)
    else:
        output_dict[key_] = input_node
    return output_dict
```

which produces:

```py
{
  owner.name.first_name: Steven,
  owner.name.last_name: Smith,
  owner.lottery_nums.0: 1,
  owner.lottery_nums.1: 2,
  owner.lottery_nums.2: 3,
  owner.lottery_nums.3: four,
  owner.lottery_nums.4: 11,
  owner.lottery_nums.5: None,
  owner.tuple: (1, 2, 'three'),
  owner.tuple_with_dict: (1, 2, 'three', {'is_valid': False}),
  owner.set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 'five'},
  owner.children.0.name.first_name: Jessica,
  owner.children.0.name.last_name: Smith,
  owner.children.1.name.first_name: George,
  owner.children.1.name.last_name: Smith,
}
```

A makeshift solution and it's not perfect.
NOTE:

- it doesn't keep empty dicts such as the `address: {}` k/v pair.
- it won't flatten dicts in nested tuples - though it would be easy to add using the fact that python tuples act similar to lists.

Comment: Possibly identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186053/3433625. Not sure which solution is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Variation of this [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys/41689055#41689055) with max_level and custom reducer.

```
  def flatten(d, max_level=None, reducer='tuple'):
      if reducer == 'tuple':
          reducer_seed = tuple()
          reducer_func = lambda x, y: (*x, y)
      else:
          raise ValueError(f'Unknown reducer: {reducer}')

      def impl(d, pref, level):
        return reduce(
            lambda new_d, kv:
                (max_level is None or level < max_level)
                and isinstance(kv[1], dict)
                and {**new_d, **impl(kv[1], reducer_func(pref, kv[0]), level + 1)}
                or {**new_d, reducer_func(pref, kv[0]): kv[1]},
                d.items(),
            {}
        )

      return impl(d, reducer_seed, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion in order to flatten your dictionary.

```py
import collections


def flatten(
    nested_dict,
    seperator='.',
    name=None,
):
    flatten_dict = {}

    if not nested_dict:
        return flatten_dict

    if isinstance(
        nested_dict,
        collections.abc.MutableMapping,
    ):
        for key, value in nested_dict.items():
            if name is not None:
                flatten_dict.update(
                    flatten(
                        nested_dict=value,
                        seperator=seperator,
                        name=f'{name}{seperator}{key}',
                    ),
                )
            else:
                flatten_dict.update(
                    flatten(
                        nested_dict=value,
                        seperator=seperator,
                        name=key,
                    ),
                )
    else:
        flatten_dict[name] = nested_dict

    return flatten_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nested_dict = {
        1: 'a',
        2: {
            3: 'c',
            4: {
                5: 'e',
            },
            6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ],
        },
    }

    print(
        flatten(
            nested_dict=nested_dict,
        ),
    )
```

Output:

```json
{
   "1":"a",
   "2.3":"c",
   "2.4.5":"e",
   "2.6":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(dictionary, prefix = '', separator = '_'):
    out_dict = {}
    if type(dictionary) != dict:
        out_dict[prefix] = dictionary
        return out_dict
    elif dictionary is None:
        return None
    for k in dictionary.keys():
        if prefix:
            prefix_n = prefix + f'{separator}{k}'
        else:
            prefix_n = k
        out_dict.update(flatten_new(dictionary[k], prefix_n))
    return out_dict
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c_a': 2, 'c_b_x': 5, 'c_b_y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: "flatten_new" is not defined. Can you edit your solution?