# Find Max in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d = {
    "local": {
        "count": 1,
        "health-beauty": {
            "count": 1,
            "tanning": {"count": 1}
        }
    },
    "nationwide": {"count": 9.0},
    "travel": {"count": 0}
}
```

In this instance `"nationwide"` is the largest.

Code is below to make it easier to attach to scripts:

```
d = {'travel': {'count': 0}, 'local': {'count': 1, 'health-beauty': {'count': 1, 'tanning': {'count': 1}}}, 'nationwide': {'count': 9.0}}
```

Comment: Was looking at `print max(d, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: you should have made local.tanning the biggest ... as it is none of the answers would find it...

Comment: If "tanning" was 10, and you need to catch that, you might need to flatten the dictionary. Try something like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: @sehe check the top answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6043835/1405399) question. It has example.

Comment: Dropping links as answers is frowned upon. At least show the gist of the answer, adapting it to the specific question. Otherwise, this is not an answer and should have been a comment (possibly a suggested duplicate)

Comment: @sehe I have subsequently realized that this should have been a comment. The reason that I ended up with posting an answer is that I lack the score for comments.
Anyhow, here's the example of the result:
`>>> x = {
        'a':1,
        'b':2,
        'c':{
            'aa':11,
            'bb':22,
            'cc':{
                'aaa':111
            }
        }
    }

>>> {'_'.join(k):v for k,v in flattenDict(x).items()}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c_aa': 11, 'c_bb': 22, 'c_cc_aaa': 111}`

Let me know once you get this comment, so I can delete the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> max(d, key=lambda x: d[x]['count'])
'nationwide'
```

Comment: this wont work .. say if your internal dict is biggest(since it doesnt even consider the nested dictionaries)

Comment: change `d['local']['tanning']["count"]` to `10` I will bet you that it doesnt return tanning ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I know it. Just that each count (as I understand) is the sum of nested dictionaries. If `d['local']['tanning']['count']` is `10`, `d['local']['count']` is also `10`(or more)... So no need to check

Comment: @JBernardo exactly, I ++ each parent too!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for nested dictionary:

```
def find_max(d, name=None):
    return max((v, name) if k == "count" else find_max(v, k) for k, v in d.items())

>>> find_max(d)
(9.0, 'nationwide')
```

Comment: that wont work I dont think... local has a key count and more entries that each have their own count...