# Accessing python sub list to import into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import fantasy basketball data from [yql](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yql/) into a pandas data frame, but I'm running into issues with the nested content.

The data from yql (results.rows) looks like this (when I use type(results.rows) I get list).

```
{u'display_position': u'PF',
u'editorial_player_key': u'nba.p.4175',
u'editorial_team_abbr': u'Uta',
u'editorial_team_full_name': u'Utah Jazz',
u'editorial_team_key': u'nba.t.26',
u'eligible_positions': {u'position': u'PF'},
u'headshot': {u'size': u'small',
  u'url': u'http://l.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/KjAPlP83IIrP9iReWfjyjw--/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTIxNTtjcj0xO2N3PTE2NDtkeD0xO2R5PTE7Zmk9dWxjcm9wO2g9NjA7cT0xMDA7dz00Ng--/http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/sp/v/nba/players_l/20101116/4175.jpg'},
  u'image_url': u'http://l.yimg.com/iu/api/res/1.2/KjAPlP83IIrP9iReWfjyjw--/YXBwaWQ9eXZpZGVvO2NoPTIxNTtjcj0xO2N3PTE2NDtkeD0xO2R5PTE7Zmk9dWxjcm9wO2g9NjA7cT0xMDA7dz00Ng--/http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/sp/v/nba/players_l/20101116/4175.jpg',
u'is_undroppable': u'0',
u'name': {u'ascii_first': u'Paul',
  u'ascii_last': u'Millsap',
  u'first': u'Paul',
  u'full': u'Paul Millsap',
  u'last': u'Millsap'},
u'player_id': u'4175',
u'player_key': u'304.p.4175',
u'position_type': u'P',
u'uniform_number': u'24'}
```

When I perform

```
DataFrame(results.rows)
```

it imports the data fine, however the data in both headshot and name are imported as columns with their nested lists.

I can access the sublist from iPython, however when I try to import it into a dataframe I get an error:

```
results[0]['name']

{u'ascii_first': u'Pau',
 u'ascii_last': u'Gasol',
 u'first': u'Pau',
 u'full': u'Pau Gasol',
 u'last': u'Gasol'}

 DataFrame([results[0]['name'])

 ValueError: If use all scalar values, must pass index
```

The behaviour that I want is to import the nested lists as their own columns rather than as a column containing the nested list. How can I do this?

The end result that I would like is for a DataFrame with the following layout:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|display_position | (...) | ascii_first | ascii_last | first | full | last | player_id  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    Data         |       |             |            |       |      |      |            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post a mock-up of what the result should look like? It's not clear from your description what you want. Moreover, are you sure you want to use DataFrame and not Series?

Comment: Sure - just updated the question. Just to make it clear, this entry is just an example of the data, there's a bunch more entries for each player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "flatten" the dictionaries contained in `results.rows`. In your case, `results[n]` ( where `n` is a zero based index representing an individual "record" ) is a dict that contains nested dicts ( for keys `name` and `headshot` ).

Flattening of dicts has been discussed in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys) and its linked questions.

One possible approach:

```
import collections

def flatten(d, parent_key=''):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + '_' + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

flattened_records = [flatten(record) for record in results.rows]
df = DataFrame(flattened_records)
```

Note that, with this approach, the keys of the nested columns will be derived by concatenating the "parent" key with the key in the nested dict eg "name_first", "name_last". You can customize the `flatten` method to change that.

More than one approach can be used here. The key insight is that you need to flatten the dictionaries contained in `results.rows`.

Comment: Great thanks. I'd had an inkling that's what I needed to do. I don't completely understand the function, but I'm sure once I've increased my python skills it will be clear to me how this works. For the mean time I'm just happy that it does work!