# Flatten Python Dict for All Values Down to True/False

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say I have a Python dict that may contain other dicts nested to an arbitrary level.  Also, some of the keys refer to boolean choices while others don't.  Something like this:

```
{'Key1': 'none',
 'Key2': {'Key2a': True, 'Key2b': False},
 'Key3': {'Key3a': {'Key3a1': 'some', 'Key3a2': 'many'}, 'Key3b': True}}
```

What I'd like to do is transform it into this:

```
{'Key1_none': 1,
 'Key2_Key2a': 1,
 'Key2_Key2b': 0,
 'Key3_Key3a_Key3a1_some': 1,
 'Key3_Key3a_Key3a2_many': 1,
 'Key3b': 1}
```

Now now only is the dict flattened, all of the keys now have boolean answers.  [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys) is a great start, but I'm not that familiar with Python.  The solution I linked to handles most of the cases, but it doesn't drill-down to the value level in all cases.  With the example above, it would leave the first part as:

```
{'Key1': 'none',
 'Key2_Key2a': 1,
 'Key2_Key2b': 0,
 ...}
```

Obviously replacing the True/False with 1/0 is trivial.  My question is more about how to flatten down to the additional level when the value of the key is not True or False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this recursive function should do it:

```
def flatten(d, prefix=''):
    prefix = prefix + '_' if prefix else ''
    new = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, bool):
            new[prefix + k] = int(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            new.update(flatten(v, prefix=prefix + k))
        elif isinstance(v, basestring):  # python3 -- str
            new[prefix + k + '_' + v] = 1
        else:
            raise TypeError('Unknown item type.')
    return new
```

the recursion happens if the value is a dict and the "prefix" for the keys is appended to whatever the previous level of nesting's prefix was.

Of course, you can do better by using proper ABCs in the `isinstance` checking... e.g.

```
bool -> numbers.Integral
dict -> collections.Mapping
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious about the line that you've commented with `# python3 -- str`.  I'm using Python 2.7.  What were you referring to here?

Comment: On python2.x there are 2 distinct string types (`str` and `unicode`) that both inherit from `basestring` so that the `isinstance` check there will pass with either a `str` or a `unicode` object.  On python3.x, the type `unicode` disappears (sort of ...) and _all_ strings act like python2.x's `unicode`.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution, based on [solution you're provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

```
import collections

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            if isinstance(v, bool):
                items.append((new_key, int(v)))
            else:
                items.append((new_key, 1))
    return dict(items
```