# Extract results from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
  D = { "America": { "Washington": { "Seattle": ('park', 'museum'), "Kent": ("market",) }, 'Colorado': { "Boulder": ("hiking",) } } }
```

how can I make the following results using that dictionary.

```
America Wahington Seattle park
America Wahington Seattle museum
America Wahington Kent market
America Colorado Boulder hiking
```

I tried as follows:

for x in D.iteritems():
    print x

Could not figure out how to extract each elements after that.
Alos wan to to how is the good way of getting the above result.

Comment: If it is always nested three levels deep as in your example, you have to use a three level nested `for` loop too. Or use recursion.

Comment: You can work into the direction of flattening the dictionary to solve it in a generic fashion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This versions should be more readable for you. But they are not so universal like other versions.

```
for country in D:
    for state in D[country]:
        for city in D[country][state]:
            for place in D[country][state][city]:
                print(country, state, city, place)


for country, A in D.items():
    for state, B in A.items():
        for city, C in B.items():
            for place in C:
                print(country, state, city, place)
```

Comment: +1 for lols... I don't even think to write specific solutions 9/10 times, and honestly this didn't even occur to me :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution almost entirely based on the ["recursive"-approach answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027615/771848) for the "flattening the dictionary" problem:

```
import collections


def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep=' '):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)
```

Usage:

```
$ ipython -i test.py
In [1]: D = {"America": {"Washington": {"Seattle": ('park', 'museum'), "Kent": ("market",)},
   ...:                  'Colorado': {"Boulder": ("hiking",)}}}

In [2]: for key, values in flatten(D, sep=" ").items():
   ...:     for value in values:
   ...:         print(key + " " + value)
   ...:         
America Washington Seattle park
America Washington Seattle museum
America Colorado Boulder hiking
America Washington Kent market
```

One of the biggest advantages of this approach is that it is *scalable* -  it would work for different depths of the dictionary `D`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is your friend...

```
D = { "America": { "Washington": { "Seattle": ('park', 'museum'), "Kent": ("market",) }, 'Colorado': { "Boulder": ("hiking",) } } }

def printOut(d,s):
    if(type(d)==dict):
        for k in d.keys():
            printOut(d[k],s+" "+str(k)) # add the key to a string and pass the contained dictionary and the new string to the same function. (this is the recursive part...)
    else:
        try:                      # this try catch allows the method to handle iterable and non-iterable leaf nodes in your dictionary.
            for k in d:
                print s+" "+str(k)
        except TypeError:
                print s+" "+str(d)

printOut(D,"")
```

prints::

```
 America Washington Seattle park
 America Washington Seattle museum
 America Washington Kent market
 America Colorado Boulder hiking
```

notice that there is a leading space so this code might fail a test if it looking for a specific output, to eliminate the leading space we would simply add the line `s = s[1:] if len(s)>0 else s` immediately after the else.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest recursive solution  to work with your different kind of data:

```
def printX(data, prefix=''):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for itemKey, itemValue in data.iteritems():
            newPrefix = '{} {}'.format(prefix, itemKey)
            printX(itemValue, newPrefix)
    elif isinstance(data, tuple):
        for itemValue in data:
            printX(itemValue, prefix)
    else:
        print('{} {}'.format(prefix, data))
```

Did a test as below:

```
D = {
    'America': { 
        'Washington': {
            'Seattle': ('park', 'museum'),
            'Kent': ('market',) 
        },
        'Colorado': {
            'Boulder': ('hiking',)
        } 
    } 
}
printX(D)
```

Output is as below

```
America Washington Seattle park
America Washington Seattle museum
America Washington Kent market
America Colorado Boulder hiking
```