# How to reduce depth of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {'a': {'b': {'c': 1}}, 'd': {'e': 1}}
```

I want to transform it to:

```
data = {'a.b': {'c': 1}, 'd': {'e': 1}}
```

Basically I want to flatten the dictionary to depth 2.

Currently I am using the following functions:

```
def flatten(metrics, parent_key='', sep='.'):
    items = []
    for k, v in metrics.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
            items.extendflatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

def dictify_again(self, metrics):
    items = {}
    for k, v in metrics.items():
        keys = k.split('.')
        k1 = '.'.join(keys[:-1])
        k2 = keys[-1]
        if k1 in items:
            items[k1][k2] = v
        else:
            items[k1] = {k2 : v}
    return items
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: how should this case `{'a': {'b': {'c': [{'f': {'g': 100} }] }}, 'd': {'e': 1}}` be transformed?

Comment: I dont have to deal with data like this. But if I had to, it should be transformed to: {'a.b.c.f': {'g': 100}, 'd': {'e': 1}}

Comment: How should this case `{'a': {'b1': {'c': 1}, 'b2': {'c': 1}}}` be transformed? Into two separate `a.b1` and `a.b2`, or...?

Comment: Try this question (not exactly what you ask for, but really close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys

Comment: the function flatten() is from that link :)

Comment: @ArindamChoudhury - so, it should be `a.b1` but then just ` b2`. What rules do you use to figure that out? "nest unless already nested"? Does order matter? Like an alphabetical thing?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: sorry  {'a': {'b1': {'c': 1}, 'b2': {'c': 1}}} is should be {'a.b1': {'c': 1}, 'a.b2': {'c': 1}}.