# Definition of a "flattened" for a generic dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, data-structures

I recently stumbled over the statement "results should be delivered as a flattened dictionary" in context to JSON-result of a web-service.

While the connection between JSON and (multi-level) Dictionary is clear to me I am confused as to what the flattened form should be. For a single-level dictionary where the values to all keys are objects I suspect the flattened form is merely a list of the objects. However, what is the answer in the generic dictionary where some values are dictionaries once again? Is it a list of all the bottom-level objects?

Thanks for all the support!

Comment: I'm guessing it simply means the dictionary should not contain any dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you Christian - am I right in the assumption that there is no general approach on how to flatten a dictionary with nested dictionaries?

Comment: No, there are several Q&A's here dedicated to flattening dictionaries. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys.