# flatten nested Python dictionaries, compressing keys, and recuring into sub-lists with dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been using [imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897/imran)'s great answer to [flatten nested Python dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027615/1638423) and am trying to think of a way to *further flatten* the dictionaries that may be inside *list* values of the dictionary *items*.
*(Of course, as my data is usually coming from XML this can also be recursive...)*

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import MutableMapping

def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)
```

Given a dict `d` like this:

```
d = {"a": 1,
     "b": 2,
     "c": {"sub-a": "one",
           "sub-b": "two",
           "sub-c": "thre"}}
```

this works great:

```
pprint(flatten(d))

        {'a': 1,
         'b': 2,
         'c_sub-a': 'one',
         'c_sub-b': 'two',
         'c_sub-c': 'thre'}
```

However, I would like to further recur through a *list value* of the dict items, and inspect if that each dict in the list can be further flattened.

Here's an example of sample input with `c-list` as a nested list value:

```
d = {"a": 1,
     "b": 2,
     "c-list": [
         {"id": 1, "nested": {"sub-a": "one", "sub-b": "two", "sub-c": "thre"} },
         {"id": 2, "nested": {"sub-a": "one", "sub-b": "two", "sub-c": "thre"} },
         {"id": 3, "nested": {"sub-a": "one", "sub-b": "two", "sub-c": "thre"} }]}
```

Here's what I currently get with the function above:

```
pprint(flatten(d))

{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c-list': [{'id': 1, 'nested': {'sub-a': 'one', 'sub-b': 'two', 'sub-c': 'thre'}},
            {'id': 2, 'nested': {'sub-a': 'one', 'sub-b': 'two', 'sub-c': 'thre'}},
            {'id': 3, 'nested': {'sub-a': 'one', 'sub-b': 'two', 'sub-c': 'thre'}}]}
```

Below is the output I'm looking for, retaining all the functionality of the original `flatten()`:

```
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c-list': [{'id': 1, 'nested_sub-a': 'one', 'nested_sub-b': 'two', 'nested_sub-c': 'thre'},
            {'id': 2, 'nested_sub-a': 'one', 'nested_sub-b': 'two', 'nested_sub-c': 'thre'},
            {'id': 3, 'nested_sub-a': 'one', 'nested_sub-b': 'two', 'nested_sub-c': 'thre'}]}
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to recursively "re-assemble" the  dict into this when it contains lists... any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close, if a value is a list, then a single line is needed to gets you to a recursive version of `flatten`:

```
items.append((new_key, map(flatten, v)))  # for python 2.x
# or
items.append((new_key, list(map(flatten, v))))  # for python 3.x
```

So, you simply **recursively call the function** on each element.

Here is how `flatten` then would look like:

```
def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(parent_key,sep,k) if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            # apply itself to each element of the list - that's it!
            items.append((new_key, map(flatten, v)))
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)
```

This solution can cope with **an arbitrary depth of *lists in lists***.

Comment: Why are you using `lambda x: flatten(x)`, not just `flatten`?

Comment: Interestingly, with my sample the output looks like this, being a map object rather than a dict:  `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c-list': <map object at 0x7ff2ca0fb320>}`

Comment: @ah you are using python 3, right?! I used python 2 where `map` returns a `list`. Simply change to `list(map(...` and you're good!

Comment: Yes, python 3.6.  I wrapped your `lambda` in a `list()` and i got the output i need.  :)  Like  so `list(map(lambda x: flatten(x), v))`.

Comment: @joefromct: please note that `list(map(flatten, v))` is completely fine and probably the [fastest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map#1247490). So there is actually no need for `lambda` in this case.

Comment: @SolomonUcko you are completely right! The `lambda` made it in there because of me *ctrl-c ctrl-v* this part form one of my scripts. :P Damn you copy-paste!

Comment: Lol. It seems a lot of people accidentally use lambda unnecessarily, by accident.

Comment: FYI, if one wanted to use a different `sep` than the default, i believe we would need the lambda.  for instance, passing in `sep='.'` would require the lambda, probably something like this:  `map(lambda x: flatten(x, parent='', sep=sep), v)`.  (the `sep=sep` would reference the `sep` originally passed in...)

Comment: The recursive call will break if the list contains something other than a `MutableMapping` (e.g. `[1,2,3]`). You can fix that by checking whether `isinstance(d,  MutableMapping)` before calling `items()`. If `d` is not a mapping, it's already "flat".

Answer (score 1):

Simply, **do a flatten for each of the dictionaries inside the list**, collect them into a new list and append it to `items` with the original key

```
def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
        items = []
        for k, v in d.items():
            new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
            if isinstance(v, MutableMapping):
                items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
            elif type(v) == list:
                items.append((new_key, [flatten(i) for i in v]))
            else:
                items.append((new_key, v))
        return dict(items)
```

Comment: but when you call `flatten` within `flatten` the you are also doing *recursion*!

Comment: @dendragon That is not what I'm talking about. That will anyway happen if there are dictionaries under dictionaries in the original code by imran.

Comment: but what you write: _iteration is faster than recursion_, does then not make much sense

Comment: Yeah, I see. I thought I am creating a new and different stack of recursion which would not hit the main stack.

Comment: List comprehension would indeed be faster than `map(lambda(..` calls. For this particular case `map` alone does the trick and there is [if any, a little speed advantage of `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map#1247490).

Comment: The simplicity and compatibility is much better here, though

Comment: Why is list comprehension more compatible than `map`? IMHO `map` is also easier to read.