# trying to reformat JSON data using python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have been trying to format live JSON data coming from an API to be read in Django views. However, data coming is little complicated.

I have incoming JSON data in format

```
    { Time1:
         {'A':'Value',
          'B':'Value',
          }
     Time2:
         {'A':'Value',
          'B':'Value',
          }
there are multiple time records....
}
```

I need to convert it into

```
{
  'Time': Time1
  'A'   : 'Value'
  'B'   : 'Value'
},
{
  'Time': Time2
  'A'   : 'Value'
  'B'   : 'Value'
},
{
  'Time': Time3
  'A'   : 'Value'
  'B'   : 'Value'
},
{
  'Time': Time4
  'A'   : 'Value'
  'B'   : 'Value'
},...and so on
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? this seems similar to [this type of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys). Although not the same, it seems it may be very similar

Comment: It's not json. There's no list `[...]` that wraps all the dictionaries, no commas between elements etc.

Comment: Python 2.7 or Python3+ ?

Comment: @MattR This is certainly not i desire. currently, i am trying to initialize an new dict with just time values and then later create a another new dict {dict1+existing dict }

Comment: @Stphane python 3+

Comment: @shivamsinghal I have posted an answer according to the Python branch you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) structure, (the code below has been tested using *Python3.6*):

```
# Given your JSON has successfully been parsed into a dictionary
> input={'Time1': {'A':'Value1A', 'B':'Value1B'}, 'Time2': {'A','Value2A', 'B', 'Value2B'}}

# Iterate over the dictionary and build a new item out of each key/value couple
> transformed=[(v.update({'Time': k}) or v) for (k, v) in input.items()]

> print(transformed)
[
  {
    'A'   : 'Value1A'
    'B'   : 'Value1B'
    'Time': 'Time1'
  },{
    'A'   : 'Value2A'
    'B'   : 'Value2B'
    'Time': 'Time2'
  }, …
]
```

What happens with `(v.update({'Time': k}) or v)` ?
Given `v` is a dictionary, `v.update(...)` will add a new entry to the instance (in other words, it mutates the instance). This method doesn't return the instance though but `None`, fortunately wrapping the call between parenthesis gives the opportunity to build an expression that will ultimately return the `v` instance. `v` being a dict object (given it is not empty) it will be evaluated truthfully in a Boolean context, hence the `(… or v)` construct.

Comment: This was really helpful.

Comment: Useful answer on merging dictonaries in case you need it: [merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression#answer-26853961)

Comment: @shivamsinghal please consider set your question as solved by ticking the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a proper `dict` format incoming. You can do this

```
in_json = { 2014: {'A':'Value', 'B':'Value'}, 2015: {'A':'Value', 'B':'Value'}}
newl = list()

for k in in_json:
    x = dict({'Time':k})
    x.update(in_json[2014])
    newl.append(x)
```

Basically just adding the `key` from the original dict as a value to a dict and appending it to the list

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, indicated output format is a list. 
In this case you'll just add the new entry for "Time" for each nested dict:

```
final_list = []
 for key, subdict in in_dict.iteritems():
     subdict["Time"] = key 
     final_list.append(subdict)
```

Or if you prefer inline:

```
final_list = [dict([("Time", key)] + sub.items()) for key, sub in in_dict.iteritems()]
```