# How to flatten multilevel/nested JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert JSON to CSV file, that I can use for further analysis. Issue with my structure is that I have quite some nested dict/lists when I convert my JSON file.

I tried to use pandas `json_normalize()`, but it only flattens first level.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from cs import CloudStack

api_key = xxxx
secret = xxxx
endpoint = xxxx

cs = CloudStack(endpoint=endpoint,
                key=api_key,
                secret=secret)

virtual_machines = cs.virtMach()

test = json_normalize(virtual_machines["virtualmachine"])

test.to_csv("test.csv", sep="|", index=False)
```

Any idea how to flatter whole JSON file, so I can create single line input to CSV file for single (in this case virtual machine) entry? I have tried couple of solutions posted here, but my result was always only first level was flattened.

This is sample JSON (in this case, I still get "securitygroup" and "nic" output as JSON format:

```
{
    "count": 13,
    "virtualmachine": [
        {
            "id": "1082e2ed-ff66-40b1-a41b-26061afd4a0b",
            "name": "test-2",
            "displayname": "test-2",
            "securitygroup": [
                {
                    "id": "9e649fbc-3e64-4395-9629-5e1215b34e58",
                    "name": "test",
                    "tags": []
                }
            ],
            "nic": [
                {
                    "id": "79568b14-b377-4d4f-b024-87dc22492b8e",
                    "networkid": "05c0e278-7ab4-4a6d-aa9c-3158620b6471"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3d7f2818-1f19-46e7-aa98-956526c5b1ad",
                    "networkid": "b4648cfd-0795-43fc-9e50-6ee9ddefc5bd"
                    "traffictype": "Guest"
                }
            ],
            "hypervisor": "KVM",
            "affinitygroup": [],
            "isdynamicallyscalable": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: there are good examples [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) - The flatten json function mentioned there should do exactly what you're looking for. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hello, this link was indeed very helpful. Partially solved my issue, though now everything is flattened, not just internal dictionaries. But I found exact same question there as well, which led to documentation for json_normalization(), which shows you can specify depth of export. [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#normalization)

Comment: Yes `json_normalize` is very useful! Give it a go and let us know how it goes.

Comment: So basically that worked - I used json_normalization(), where I defined structure of output as mentioned in link above. Thank you gyx again for all the help. Can you also maybe post it as answer, so I can mark it as solution?

Comment: That's great. And no you can post your own answer (since you answered it) and mark it as the answer :)

Comment: You need to add a comma(,) before `"traffictype"`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I used the following function (details can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)):

```
def flatten_data(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out
```

This unfortunately completely flattens whole JSON, meaning that if you have multi-level JSON (many nested dictionaries), it might flatten everything into single line with tons of columns.

What I used, in the end, was `json_normalize()` and specified structure that I required. A nice example of how to do it that way can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#normalization).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid flattening arrays at their final level?

Answer (score 16):

Cross-posting (but then adapting further) from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62186053/4355695 : In this repo: https://github.com/ScriptSmith/socialreaper/blob/master/socialreaper/tools.py#L8 , I found an implementation of the [list-inclusion comment by @roneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys#comment99288620_6027615) to the [answer posted by @Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027615/4355695).

I've added checks to it for catching empty lists and empty dicts. And also added print lines that will help one understand precisely how this function works. You can turn off those print statemenents by setting `crumbs=False`

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
crumbs = True
def flatten(dictionary, parent_key=False, separator='.'):
    """
    Turn a nested dictionary into a flattened dictionary
    :param dictionary: The dictionary to flatten
    :param parent_key: The string to prepend to dictionary's keys
    :param separator: The string used to separate flattened keys
    :return: A flattened dictionary
    """

    items = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if crumbs: print('checking:',key)
        new_key = str(parent_key) + separator + key if parent_key else key
        if isinstance(value, MutableMapping):
            if crumbs: print(new_key,': dict found')
            if not value.items():
                if crumbs: print('Adding key-value pair:',new_key,None)
                items.append((new_key,None))
            else:
                items.extend(flatten(value, new_key, separator).items())
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            if crumbs: print(new_key,': list found')
            if len(value):
                for k, v in enumerate(value):
                    items.extend(flatten({str(k): v}, new_key, separator).items())
            else:
                if crumbs: print('Adding key-value pair:',new_key,None)
                items.append((new_key,None))
        else:
            if crumbs: print('Adding key-value pair:',new_key,value)
            items.append((new_key, value))
    return dict(items)
```

Test it:

```
ans = flatten({'a': 1, 'c': {'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, 'd': [1, 2, 3], 'e':{'f':[], 'g':{}} })
print('\nflattened:',ans)
```

Output:

```
checking: a
Adding key-value pair: a 1
checking: c
c : dict found
checking: a
Adding key-value pair: c.a 2
checking: b
c.b : dict found
checking: x
Adding key-value pair: c.b.x 5
checking: y
Adding key-value pair: c.b.y 10
checking: d
d : list found
checking: 0
Adding key-value pair: d.0 1
checking: 1
Adding key-value pair: d.1 2
checking: 2
Adding key-value pair: d.2 3
checking: e
e : dict found
checking: f
e.f : list found
Adding key-value pair: e.f None
checking: g
e.g : dict found
Adding key-value pair: e.g None

flattened: {'a': 1, 'c.a': 2, 'c.b.x': 5, 'c.b.y': 10, 'd.0': 1, 'd.1': 2, 'd.2': 3, 'e.f': None, 'e.g': None}
```

Annd that does the job I need done: I throw any complicated json at this and it flattens it out for me. I added a check to the original code to handle empty lists too

Credits to https://github.com/ScriptSmith whose repo I found the intial flatten function in.

Testing OP's sample json, here's the output:

```
{'count': 13,
 'virtualmachine.0.id': '1082e2ed-ff66-40b1-a41b-26061afd4a0b',
 'virtualmachine.0.name': 'test-2',
 'virtualmachine.0.displayname': 'test-2',
 'virtualmachine.0.securitygroup.0.id': '9e649fbc-3e64-4395-9629-5e1215b34e58',
 'virtualmachine.0.securitygroup.0.name': 'test',
 'virtualmachine.0.securitygroup.0.tags': None,
 'virtualmachine.0.nic.0.id': '79568b14-b377-4d4f-b024-87dc22492b8e',
 'virtualmachine.0.nic.0.networkid': '05c0e278-7ab4-4a6d-aa9c-3158620b6471',
 'virtualmachine.0.nic.1.id': '3d7f2818-1f19-46e7-aa98-956526c5b1ad',
 'virtualmachine.0.nic.1.networkid': 'b4648cfd-0795-43fc-9e50-6ee9ddefc5bd',
 'virtualmachine.0.nic.1.traffictype': 'Guest',
 'virtualmachine.0.hypervisor': 'KVM',
 'virtualmachine.0.affinitygroup': None,
 'virtualmachine.0.isdynamicallyscalable': False}
```

So you'll see that 'tags' and 'affinitygroup' keys are also handled and added to output. Original code was omitting them.

2021-05-30 : Updated: collections.MutableMapping is changed to collections.abc.MutableMapping

2023-01-11 : edited, added separator arg in second items.extend() call as advised by @MHebes

2024-02-20 : how did that .abc go missing from the import statement?

Comment: `items.extend(flatten({str(k): v}, new_key).items())` needs to forward the `seperator` argument

Comment: @MHebes sorry, didn't get you.. can you give the modified code line pls? else pls feel free to submit another answer with the improved code

Comment: Sure, the fix is `items.extend(flatten({str(k): v}, new_key, separator).items())`. This ensures that the `separator` argument gets passed down to nested levels. You do this in the `if ... MutableMapping` branch, but not the `elif ... list` branch.

Answer (score 15):

IMO [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379007/5997596) doesn't properly handle JSON array.

If JSON object has array as value then it should be flattened to array of objects like

```py
{'a': [1, 2]} -> [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
```

instead of adding index to key.

And nested objects should be flattened by concatenating keys (e.g. with dot as separator) like

```py
{'a': {'b': 1}} -> {'a.b': 1}
```

(and this is done correctly in accepted one).

With all these requirements I've ended up with following (developed and used in **CPython3.5.3**):

```py
from functools import (partial,
                       singledispatch)
from itertools import chain
from typing import (Dict,
                    List,
                    TypeVar)

Serializable = TypeVar('Serializable', None, int, bool, float, str,
                       dict, list, tuple)
Array = List[Serializable]
Object = Dict[str, Serializable]


def flatten(object_: Object,
            *,
            path_separator: str = '.') -> Array[Object]:
    """
    Flattens given JSON object into list of objects with non-nested values.

    >>> flatten({'a': 1})
    [{'a': 1}]
    >>> flatten({'a': [1, 2]})
    [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
    >>> flatten({'a': {'b': None}})
    [{'a.b': None}]
    >>> flatten({'a': [1, 2], 'b': []})
    [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]
    """
    keys = set(object_)
    result = [dict(object_)]
    while keys:
        key = keys.pop()
        new_result = []
        for index, record in enumerate(result):
            try:
                value = record[key]
            except KeyError:
                new_result.append(record)
            else:
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    del record[key]
                    new_value = flatten_nested_objects(
                            value,
                            prefix=key + path_separator,
                            path_separator=path_separator
                    )
                    keys.update(new_value.keys())
                    new_result.append({**new_value, **record})
                elif isinstance(value, list):
                    del record[key]
                    new_records = [
                        flatten_nested_objects(sub_value,
                                               prefix=key + path_separator,
                                               path_separator=path_separator)
                        for sub_value in value
                    ]
                    keys.update(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.keys,
                                                        new_records)))
                    if new_records:
                        new_result.extend({**new_record, **record}
                                          for new_record in new_records)
                    else:
                        new_result.append(record)
                else:
                    new_result.append(record)
        result = new_result
    return result


@singledispatch
def flatten_nested_objects(object_: Serializable,
                           *,
                           prefix: str = '',
                           path_separator: str) -> Object:
    return {prefix[:-len(path_separator)]: object_}


@flatten_nested_objects.register(dict)
def _(object_: Object,
      *,
      prefix: str = '',
      path_separator: str) -> Object:
    result = dict(object_)
    for key in list(result):
        result.update(flatten_nested_objects(result.pop(key),
                                             prefix=(prefix + key
                                                     + path_separator),
                                             path_separator=path_separator))
    return result


@flatten_nested_objects.register(list)
def _(object_: Array,
      *,
      prefix: str = '',
      path_separator: str) -> Object:
    return {prefix[:-len(path_separator)]: list(map(partial(
            flatten_nested_objects,
            path_separator=path_separator),
            object_))}
```

Comment: If I call flatten on a nested object, I wouldn't expect any sub-elements in this anymore. I would expect a single top level iterable, not an iterable that *might* contain sub-structs.

I would say your implementation returns a list of flattened items, but not that the returned value is flat (unless you provide an already flat list eg: [1,2,3,4,5]).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I really think that this should be the default behavior of `flatten_json`. Thank you !

Comment: This doesn't handle the case when JSON object has an `empty` array as value. Could you please let me know how to handle it ?

Comment: @abdelgha4: how it "doesn't handle the case when JSON object has an empty array as value"? can you please provide an example with expected & actual behavior?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov : For example `flatten({'a': [1, 2], 'b': []})` returns `[]`, while I expect `[{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}]` just like the result of `flatten({'a': [1, 2], 'b': {}})`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov great solution. also currently `flatten({'a': {'b': [None]}})` returns `[{'a.b.': None}]` while `flatten({'a': {'b': None}})` returns `[{'a.b': None}]`. I think the key should be the same in both outputs.

Comment: I don't know if you have time for this, but I think theses would be some great features to have:


- control the level of flattening. Perhaps a `max_depth`  or `keys_not_to_flatten` arguments.  
`flatten({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4], 'c': {'d': [5, 6]}}, max_depth=1, keys_not_to_flatten=['b'])`
`->` `[{'a': 1, 'c': "{'d': [5, 6]}", 'b': '[3, 4]'},
 {'a': 2, 'c': "{'d': [5, 6]}", 'b': '[3, 4]'}]`


- boolean argument `split_arrays`, to switch between current behavior (splitting arrays), and adding index to keys.


I wish I could work on this but it's a bit advanced for me :).

Comment: how to do use above code and flatten the json and store in spark dataframe, as above code takes too much time to flatten large data files.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else finds themselves here and is looking for a solution better suited to subsequent programmatic treatment:

Flattening the lists creates the need to process the headings for list lengths etc. I wanted a solution where if there are 2 lists of e.g. 2 elements then there would be four rows generated yielding each valid potential data row (see below for actual examples):

```
class MapFlattener:

    def __init__(self):
        self.headings = []
        self.rows = []

    def add_rows(self, headings, rows):
        self.headings = [*self.headings, *headings]
        if self.rows:
            new_rows = []
            for base_row in self.rows:
                for row in rows:
                    new_rows.append([*base_row, *row])
            self.rows = new_rows
        else:
            self.rows = rows

    def __call__(self, mapping):
        for heading, value in mapping.items():
            if isinstance(value, Mapping):
                sub_headings, sub_rows = MapFlattener()(value)
                sub_headings = [f'{heading}:{sub_heading}' for sub_heading in sub_headings]
                self.add_rows(sub_headings, sub_rows)
                continue

            if isinstance(value, list):
                self.add_rows([heading], [[e] for e in value])
                continue

            self.add_rows([heading], [[value]])

        return self.headings, self.rows


def map_flatten(mapping):
    return MapFlattener()(mapping)
```

This creates output more in line with relational data:

```
In [22]: map_flatten({'l': [1,2]})                                                                                                          
Out[22]: (['l'], [[1], [2]])

In [23]: map_flatten({'l': [1,2], 'n': 7})                                                                                                  
Out[23]: (['l', 'n'], [[1, 7], [2, 7]])

In [24]: map_flatten({'l': [1,2], 'n': 7, 'o': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}})                                                                           
Out[24]: (['l', 'n', 'o:a', 'o:b'], [[1, 7, 1, 2], [2, 7, 1, 2]])

In [25]: map_flatten({'top': {'middle': {'bottom': [0, 1]}, 'ml': ['A', 'B']}, 'l': ['a', 'b']})                                             
Out[25]: 
(['top:middle:bottom', 'top:ml', 'l'],
 [[0, 'A', 'a'],
  [0, 'A', 'b'],
  [0, 'B', 'a'],
  [0, 'B', 'b'],
  [1, 'A', 'a'],
  [1, 'A', 'b'],
  [1, 'B', 'a'],
  [1, 'B', 'b']])
```

This is particularly useful if you are using the csv in spreadsheets etc. and need to process the flattened data.

Comment: How can we extend this for multiple levels.?

Comment: It is recursive, it already works for multiple levels. I've edited the answer to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with BFS approach, where I'm storing (parent,val) in queue only if val is dict type.

```
def flattern_json(d):
    if len(d) == 0:
        return {}
    from collections import deque
    q = deque()
    res = dict()
    for key, val in d.items(): # This loop push the top most keys and values into queue.
        if not isinstance(val, dict):  # If it's not dict
            if isinstance(val, list):  # If it's list then check list values if it contains dict object.
                temp = list()  # Creating temp list for storing the values that we will need which are not dict.
                for v in val:
                    if not isinstance(v, dict):
                        temp.append(v)
                    else:
                        q.append((key, v))  # if it's value is dict type then we push along with parent which is key.
                if len(temp) > 0:
                    res[key] = temp
            else:
                res[key] = val
        else:
            q.append((key, val))
    while q:
        k, v = q.popleft()  # Taking parent and the value out of queue
        for key, val in v.items():
            new_parent = k + "_" + key  # New parent will be old parent_currentval
            if isinstance(val, list):
                temp = list()
                for v in val:
                    if not isinstance(v, dict):
                        temp.append(v)
                    else:
                        q.append((new_parent, v))
                if len(temp) >= 0:
                    res[new_parent] = temp
            elif not isinstance(val, dict):
                res[new_parent] = val
            else:
                q.append((new_parent, val))
    return res
```

It's working with the JSON that is given, I'm appending _ for flattening JSON instead of using 0 1 list indexing.

```
from pprint import pprint

print(pprint.pprint(flattern_json(d)))
```

It gave following output:

```
{'count': 13,
 'virtualmachine_affinitygroup': [],
 'virtualmachine_displayname': 'test-2',
 'virtualmachine_hypervisor': 'KVM',
 'virtualmachine_id': '1082e2ed-ff66-40b1-a41b-26061afd4a0b',
 'virtualmachine_isdynamicallyscalable': False,
 'virtualmachine_name': 'test-2',
 'virtualmachine_nic': [],
 'virtualmachine_nic_id': '3d7f2818-1f19-46e7-aa98-956526c5b1ad',
 'virtualmachine_nic_networkid': 'b4648cfd-0795-43fc-9e50-6ee9ddefc5bd',
 'virtualmachine_nic_traffictype': 'Guest',
 'virtualmachine_securitygroup': [],
 'virtualmachine_securitygroup_id': '9e649fbc-3e64-4395-9629-5e1215b34e58',
 'virtualmachine_securitygroup_name': 'test',
 'virtualmachine_securitygroup_tags': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def flatten(data, key=None, *, seperator="__"):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            yield from flatten(item, key)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if key:
                new_key = key + seperator + k
                yield from flatten(v, new_key)
            else:
                yield from flatten(v, k) 
    else:
        yield key, data
```

Usage:

```py
data = {
    "age": 29,
    "name": "ankit",
    "others": [
        {
            "todo": [{"title": "party"}, {"title": "buy grocceries"}],
            "hobbies": ["gym", "online games"],
        }
    ],
    "skills": ["javascript", "react"],
}

list(flatten(data))
output:
[('age', 29),
 ('name', 'ankit'),
 ('others__todo__title', 'party'),
 ('others__todo__title', 'buy grocceries'),
 ('others__hobbies', 'gym'),
 ('others__hobbies', 'online games'),
 ('skills', 'javascript'),
 ('skills', 'react')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple function to normalize and flatten data to json.
It accepts list, dict, tuple and flattens it to a json.

```
def normalize_data_to_json(raw_data: [list, dict, tuple], parent=""):
    from datetime import datetime
    from decimal import Decimal

    result = {}
    # key name normalise to snake case (single underscore)
    parent = parent.lower().replace(" ", "_") if isinstance(parent, str) else parent
    if isinstance(parent, str) and parent.startswith("__"):
        # if parent has no parent remove double underscore and treat as int if digit else as str
        # treating as int is better if passed data is a list so you output is index based dict
        parent = int(parent.lstrip("_")) if parent.lstrip("_").isdigit() else parent.lstrip("_")

    # handle str, int, float, and decimal.
    # you can easily add more data types as er your data
    if type(raw_data) in [str, int, float, Decimal]:
        result[parent] = float(raw_data) if isinstance(raw_data, Decimal) else raw_data

    # normalise datetime object
    elif isinstance(raw_data, datetime):
        result[parent] = raw_data.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    # normalise dict and all nested dicts.
    # all nests are joined with double underscore to identify parent key name with it's children
    elif isinstance(raw_data, dict):
        for k, v in raw_data.items():
            k = f'{parent}__{k}' if parent else k
            result.update(normalize_data_to_json(v, parent=k))

    # normalise list and tuple
    elif type(raw_data) in [list, tuple]:
        for i, sub_item in enumerate(raw_data, start=1):
            result.update(normalize_data_to_json(sub_item, f"{parent}__{i}"))

    # any data which did not matched above data types, normalise them using it's __str__
    else:
        result[parent] = str(raw_data)

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read tons of different methods and all. This is the only one that worked for me for complex nested JSON. This one is to flatten the nested JSON and convert it to the pandas data frame so that it is easier to filter out whatever element you want.

```
import json
import pprint
import pandas as pd
from flatten_json import flatten

with open('sth.json') as json_file:
  nested_json = json.load(json_file)
nested_json = nested_json["_via_img_metadata"]

out = {}
def flatten(x, name=''):
    if type(x) is dict:
        for a in x:
            flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
    elif type(x) is list:
        i = 0
        for a in x:
            flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
            i += 1
    else:
        out[name[:-1]] = x
    return out

df = pd.Series(flatten(nested_json)).to_frame()
```

Answer (score -1):

Outputting in jsonpath format:

```
def convert(f):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=None):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                val = '.'.join((name, a)) if name else a
                flatten(x[a], val)
        elif type(x) is list:
            for (i, a) in enumerate(x):
                flatten(a, name + f'[{str(i)}]')
        else:
            out[name] = x if x else ""
    flatten(f)
    return out
```

Answer (score -2):

Just pass your dictionary here:

```
def getKeyValuePair(dic,master_dic = {},master_key = None):
    keys = list(dic.keys())
    for key in keys:
        if type(dic[key]) == dict:
                getKeyValuePair(dic[key],master_dic = master_dic,master_key = key)
        else:
            if master_key == None:
                master_dic[key] = dic[key]
            else:
                master_dic[str(master_key)+'_'+str(key)] = dic[key]

   return master_dic
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation, also please explain as your code doesn't work after passing some dictionary.