# reading and editing json file

Tags: json, editing

I am new to Python and trying to edit a .json file that looks like the dictionary below:
 {
      "name": "MB_NDE_AX667_ECU[500-2000]",
      "physical_quantity": "acceleration",
      "unit": "m/s2",
      "okrangelow": 0,
      "okrangehigh": 10,
      "input": "ch2_ECU1.rms",
      "history": {
        "ds": 30,
        "timer": 24,
        "files": 30
      },
      "reg": 44
    },

My goal is to get another json file that will have the dictionary restructured to single line dictionary, e.g:

{"name":"MB_NDE_AX667_ECU[500-2000]","physical_quantity":"acceleration",......}

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: By "single line" do you mean a single level of keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python flatten multilevel JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359783/python-flatten-multilevel-json)

Comment: No I mean a single row of key:value pairs per dictionary - let's say 5 or 6 pairs,then the next dictionary(with 5 or 6 pairs) is on the next line and so on..

Comment: And the current situation is that each dictionary takes up more than one line? If so, please update your question to reflect that with a good example.