# seeking help regarding converting data from nested JSON to flat json in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, transform, data-science

I am looking for converting a nested json into flat json using python.
I have the data coming from an API response, the number of keys/columns can be upto 100, and the rows/overall count of elements can be 100k

```
[{"Name":"John", "Location":{"City":"Los Angeles","State":"CA"}},{"Name":"Sam", "Location":{"City":"Chicago","State":"IL"}}]
```

I did came across this
([Python flatten multilevel JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359783/python-flatten-multilevel-json))
but this flattens the whole JSON completely, as a result everything falls under one line which I am not looking for currently. I also thought of using this on one the data one array at a time in loop but that is causing a lot of load on the system

```
[{"Name":"John", "City":"Los Angeles","State":"CA"},{"Name":"Sam", "City":"Chicago","State":"IL"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unpacking with `dict.pop`:

```
[{**d.pop("Location"), **d} for d in l]
```

Output:

```
[{'City': 'Los Angeles', 'Name': 'John', 'State': 'CA'},
 {'City': 'Chicago', 'Name': 'Sam', 'State': 'IL'}]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for checking on this.
but isn't pop supposed to remove the values from dictionary, I never saw pop helping in such a way. I will try this

Comment: That's the beauty of it: `pop` removes the value so that you don't have to remove the nested dict by yourself :)

Comment: I am getting this error
```
IndexError: pop index out of range
```
I think because pop keeps on reducing the index.

Comment: Any thoughts on this.