# Python remove nested JSON key or combine key with value

Tags: python, json

I'm receiving json files improperly and am trying to create a temporary fix until the documents come in the proper format. Instead of the value being set to the derivationsValue key, it is being set as a key value pair, so there is an extraneous key. I want to set the the inner value to the outer key.

```
{        
  "derivationName": "other_lob_subcd",
  "derivationValue": {
     "OOP3": "TENANT"
  }
}
```

Given the above json, I want the result to be

```
{        
  "derivationName": "other_lob_subcd",
  "derivationValue": "TENANT"
}
```

I could also live with

```
{        
   "derivationName": "other_lob_subcd",
   "derivationValue": "OOP3-TENANT"
}
```

or something like that. It just can't be another json element.

Based on @Diana Ayala's answer, I have written this to try solving the problem with variable keys.

```
    for k,v in data['mcsResults']['derivationsOutput']:
        if isinstance(k['derivationValue'], dict):
            for sk, sv in k['derivationValue']:
                k['derivationValue'] = sv
```

Comment: which python2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example given:

```
import json

with open('inpt.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

data['derivationValue'] = data['derivationValue']['OOP3']
```

Gives the output:

```
{'derivationName': 'other_lob_subcd', 'derivationValue': 'TENANT'}
```

In general, you can look at the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359783/python-flatten-multilevel-json).

Answer (score 2):

You can use below generic code for your requirement.

```
import json

filePath = 'file.json'

def getValue(value):
    if type(value) is dict:
        ans = list(value)[0]
        for k in value:
            ans += '-'+getValue(value[k])
        return ans
    return value

def correct(data):
    for key in data:   
        data[key] = getValue(data[key]) 
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(filePath) as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        data = correct(data)
        print (data)
```

output:

```
D:\>python file.py
{'derivationName': 'other_lob_subcd', 'derivationValue': 'OOP3-TENANT'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
val = {        
   "derivationName": "other_lob_subcd",
   "derivationValue": {
      "OOP3": "TENANT"
   }
 }

val["derivationValue"] = val["derivationValue"]["OOP3"]
print(val)
```

This will be the output:

```
val = {        
   "derivationName": "other_lob_subcd",
   "derivationValue": "TENANT"
 }
```