# How to extract a nested dictionary from a STRING column in Python Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, python-re

There's a table where one data point of its column `event` looks like this:

THE 'event IS A STRING COLUMN!

```
df['event']
RETURNS:
"{'eventData': {'type': 'page', 'name': "WHAT'S UP"}, 'eventId': '1003', 'deviceType': 'kk', 'pageUrl': '/chick 2/whats sup', 'version': '1.0.0.888-10_7_2020__4_18_30', 'sessionGUID': '1b312346a-cd26-4ce6-888-f25143030e02', 'locationid': 'locakdi-3b0c-49e3-ab64-741f07fd4cb3', 'eventDescription': 'Page Load'}"
```

I'm trying to extract the nested dictionary `eventData` from the dictionary and create a new column like below:

```
df['event'] 
RETURNS: 
{'eventId': '1003', 'deviceType': 'kk', 'pageUrl': '/chick 2/whats sup', 'version': '1.0.0.888-10_7_2020__4_18_30', 'sessionGUID': '1b312346a-cd26-4ce6-888-f25143030e02', 'locationid': 'locakdi-3b0c-49e3-ab64-741f07fd4cb3', 'eventDescription': 'Page Load'}

df['eventData']
RETURNS:
{'type': 'page', 'name': "WHAT'S UP"}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using the [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method on the `event` column.

If the `eventData` key is expected to be present in the `event` column dictionary for all rows of the data frame, something below may suffice

```py
import json
import numpy as np

def get_event_data_from_event(event_str):
    """
    Convert event string to dict and return event_data
    """
    try:
        event_as_dict = json.loads(event_str)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        return np.nan
    else
        if not "eventData" in event_as_dict.keys():
            return np.nan
        return event_as_dict["eventData"]  

df["eventData"] = df["event"].apply(lambda x: get_event_data_from_event(x))
```

Which will return an N/A for that row in the `eventData` column if the `event` dictionary is not formatted as you expected it to be.

You could then drop those non-conforming rows with a [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) like so:

```py
df_subset = df.dropna(axis='columns', subset="eventData")
```

Comment: Sorry about the misleading. The 'event' column is actually a STRING column. The only way I can think of is to apply REGEX to get the second curly bracket "{ }" from that string and create a new column. Do you have any idea how to construct the regex for this case?

Comment: I've updated my answer above to expect the event column to be a string. You can use `json.loads` to load a json string as a dict/list object.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally fot the answer from another post:
[Python flatten multilevel/nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359783/python-flatten-multilevel-nested-json)

How to use:
json_col = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in df['json_column']])

```
def flatten_json(nested_json, exclude=['']):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude: flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
```