# Flatten a JSON file in Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change a JSON file to a pandas DataFrame. I have tried a number of solution such as pd.jason_normalize(data.json) but it doesn't work.

The file appears to be more complex and has nested JSON data. How do I flatten this file so I can read the contents as a DataFrame?

Images are to give context on he structure

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
data = pd.read_json("papers.json")
```

**>>>(Output)**

```
data.head(5)


paper
0   {'id': 1, 'preliminary_decision': 'accept', 'r...
1   {'id': 2, 'preliminary_decision': 'accept', 'r...
2   {'id': 3, 'preliminary_decision': 'accept', 'r...
3   {'id': 4, 'preliminary_decision': 'accept', 'r...
4   {'id': 5, 'preliminary_decision': 'accept', 'r...
```

**>>>(Output)**

```
paper[0]
```

> > {'**id**': 1,  '**preliminary_decision**': 'accept',  'review':
> > > [{'**confidence**': '4',    '**evaluation**': '1',    '**id**': 1,    '**lan**': 'es',
> > > '**orientation**': '0',    '**remarks**: '',    '**text**': '- El artículo aborda
> > > un problema contingente y muy relevante, e incluye tanto un
> > > diagnóstico nacional de uso de buenas prácticas como una solución
> > > (buenas prácticas concretas). - El lenguaje es adecuado.  - El
> > > artículo se siente como la concatenación de tres artículos diferentes:
> > > (1) resultados de una encuesta, (2) buenas prácticas de seguridad, (3)
> > > incorporación de buenas prácticas. - El orden de las secciones sería
> > > mejor si refleja este orden (la versión revisada es #2, #1, #3). - El
> > > artículo no tiene validación de ningún tipo, ni siquiera por
> > > evaluación de expertos.',    '**timespan**': '2010-07-05'},
> > > {'confidence': '4',    'evaluation': '1',    'id': 2,    'lan': 'es',
> > > 'orientation': '1',    'remarks': '',    'text': 'El artículo presenta
> > > recomendaciones prácticas para el desarrollo de software seguro. Se
> > > describen las mejores prácticas recomendadas para desarrollar software
> > > que sea proactivo ante los ataques, y se realiza un análisis de costos
> > > de estas prácticas en desarrollo de software. Todo basado en una
> > > revisión de prácticas propuestas en la bibliografía y su contraste con
> > > datos obtenidos de una encuesta en empresas. Finalmente se recomienda
> > > una guía.  Sería ideal aplicar la guía propuesta a empresas no
> > > involucradas en la encuesta que sirvió para originarla de modo de
> > > poder evaluar su efectividad en forma independiente.',    'timespan':
> > > '2010-07-05'},   {'confidence': '5',    'evaluation': '1',    'id': 3,
> > > 'lan': 'es',    'orientation': '1',    'remarks': '',    'text': '- El
> > > tema es muy interesante y puede ser de mucha ayuda una guía para
> > > incorporar prácticas de seguridad. - La presentación (descripción,
> > > etapa y uso) de las 9 prácticas para el desarrollo de software seguro.
> > > - El “estado real del desarrollo de software en Chile” (como lo indica en su paper) no se puede lograr con solamente 22 encuestas de
> > un total
> > > de 50. - Presenta nueve tablas que corresponden a las prácticas para
> > > el desarrollo de software seguro, pero la guía presenta 10 prácticas.
> > > ¿explica por qué? - Sugiero mejorar la guía, el mayor aporte está en
> > > la secuencia de incorporación que propone.  Además, no debería
> > > explicar la práctica en Observaciones ni diferenciarla con otras
> > > prácticas en esa columna, sino que debería dar sugerencias de cómo
> > > aplicarla. - En el texto indica “Más adelante, se presentan además
> > > tres prácticas extras…” ¿cuáles son o no leí correctamente? - De
> > > acuerdo a formato, poner como mínimo 5 palabras clave. - Sugiero
> > > mencionar las prácticas antes de mostrar cada tabla. - Algunas
> > > referencias están incompletas, por ejemplo, falta año en referencia
> > > 17, falta año y tipo de evento en referencia 11, falta editorial en
> > > referencia 19 (¿es un libro?) - Algunos títulos llevan una coma dentro
> > > de las comillas, ejemplo, referencia 1',    'timespan':
> > > '2010-07-05'}]}

**( Expected Output)**

[ id, preliminary_decision, review, confidence, evaluation, id,
lan, orientation,  remarks, text, timespan']

Comment: Please don't post images as they don't help us in reproducing your dataset at our ends. Instead please paste everything as text with proper sample input and expected output.

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(data.paper, record_path=['review'], meta=['id', 'preliminary_decision'], meta_prefix='paper.')`  assuming `data` is a dataframe and you have JSON in `paper` column.

Comment: @Emma. Please post your comment as answer.

Comment: I think Emma's answer works for this

Answer (score 3):

You can use some parameters to `json_normalize` to achieve what you like to get.

Assuming `data` is a dataframe and you have JSON object in paper column.

```
pd.json_normalize(data.paper, record_path=['review'], meta=['id', 'preliminary_decision'], meta_prefix='paper.')
```

You need to use either `record_prefix` or `meta_prefix` to avoid conflicts of columns, since you have `id` in root and within `review` array.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51359783/12750353)

But in your case you only want the last key to be considered

```py
def flatten_data(data):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], a)
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for i,a in enumerate(x):
                flatten(a, i)
        else:
            out[name] = x
    flatten(data);
    return out

df = pd.DataFrame([flatten(y) for y in data]);
```

Comment: Did you check this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this like so :

```py
expected_out = [ 'id', 'preliminary_decision', 'review', 'confidence', 'evaluation', 'id', 'lan', 'orientation', 'remarks', 'text', 'timespan']

import json


data = {}
with open('tmp.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Get the elems in a list, and check for subdico.
# Can be done with a for-loop or just the first element of the list
def check_list(li):
    k = []
    # for v in li:
    v = li[0]
    if type(v) is dict:
        k += get_dict_keys(v)
    elif type(v) is list:
        k += check_list(v)
    return k

# Get the keys from a dict and check for sub list/dict
def get_dict_keys(dico):
    d = dico.copy()
    keys = list(d.keys())

    for k in d.keys():
        if type(d[k]) is dict:
            keys += get_dict_keys(d[k])
        elif type(d[k]) is list:
            keys += check_list(d[k])
    return keys

print('Result:')
print(get_dict_keys(data))
print('Expected:')
print(expected_out)
```

Result:

```py
Result:
['id', 'preliminary_decision', 'review', 'confidence', 'evaluation', 'id', 'lan', 'orientation', 'remarks', 'text', 'timespan']
Expected: 
['id', 'preliminary_decision', 'review', 'confidence', 'evaluation', 'id', 'lan', 'orientation', 'remarks', 'text', 'timespan']
```