# pandas json normalize directly from file

Tags: python, json, pandas, pymongo

I am writing a wrapper class for `pymongo`. The main functionality I am aiming for is for it to be compatible with `pandas`, so that I can do this:

```py
from loader import PyMongoLoader
import pandas as pd

_loader = PyMongoLoader(url="my_url", port="my_port")
df = pd.read_json(_loader, orient="records")
```

From the pandas documentation, `pd.read_json` accepts any object with a `read` method as the first argument. Internally, I call `collection.find` and parse the result to a string using `bson.dumps`:

```py
    def read(self, size: int = -1) -> str:
        assert self._is_valid, "MongoDB connection must be valid for retrieving data"

        self.logger.debug(
            f"Retrieving documents from {self._collection}. Expected size: \033[94m{self._collection.count_documents({})}\033[0m"
        )
        result = list(self._collection.find())

        self.logger.debug(
            f"Retrieved {len(result)} documents from remote. Size of json: {sum([len(document) for document in result])}"
        )
        return dumps(result)
```

**Problem**

This works fine. However, the database I am working with has complex field names like "26344T Control Measure [5.3-10.8]". Because of these names, the data is stored as a nested json in the database. I want to be able to normalize these fields, but as far as I know, `pd.json_normalize` does not accept a path argument, only a string.

I've thought of two solutions, but neither convince me much:

- Changing the database field names. This would solve the issue, but it would be a hassle to keep in mind any time I have to add new data to the database.
- Patching `pd.resd_json` or `pd.json_normalize` in the loader source file. While this would also solve the problem, I'm sure it is not a good solution and it could potentially break other code using pandas.

**Question**

Is there a supported way to normalize a json directly from a file? If not, how can I normalize the json I'm passing to `pd.read_json` to get rid of the weird indentation problems in my database?

**Edit**

The JSON results I get from my database follow this format:

```py
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "651ec788c110096a55c8d4de"
  },
  "DateTime": "20/02/2017 15:00:00",
  "546321B": {
    "measure": 0
  },
  "538612B": {
    "measure": 80
  },
  "517713B": {
    "measure": 70
  },
  "508021V": {
    "avg": 37
  }
}
```

and I want my dataframe to be:

| DateTime | 546321B.measure | 538612B.measure | 517713B.measure | 508021V.avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "20/02/2017 15:00:00" | 0 | 80 | 70 | 37 |

Ideally, I'd want to get this result directly from `pd.read_json(loader, orient="records")`

Comment: can you give an example of the json file?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte yes, I edited the post to add an example JSON from the database as well as the output I want from it

Comment: I dont see whta is the problem using Json normalize directly! `pd.json_normalize(data)` where data is a dictionary or json you have given should give you nice results.

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Yes, I know that. But I want to use `pd.read_json(loader)` directly. For that to work, either `read_json` would have to normalize the json read from my database or I’d need to tweak my `read` method to return a json normalized string. That is what I want to be able to do.

Comment: Following your discussion I have added an answer let me know if that work for you!

Comment: There is an option to let the MongoDB server format it for you, like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QwrDn8LG4lK "link to example -->").

Answer (score 1):

If you want to normalize your data and you only have nested dictionaries and do not want to use `pd.json_normalize` you could use something like this:

```
def unest_level(data):
    for key, item in list(data.items()):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for sub_key, sub_item in item.items():
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                     sub_key, sub_item = unest_level(sub_item)
                yield f"{key}.{sub_key}", sub_item
        yield key, item
```

considering the data you have given:

```
{key: item for key, item in unest_level(data)}
>>>{'DateTime': '20/02/2017 15:00:00',
 '_id.$oid': '651ec788c110096a55c8d4de',
 '546321B.measure': 0,
 '538612B.measure': 80,
 '517713B.measure': 70,
 '508021V.avg': 37}
```

you could add this into your reader as follow:

```py
def read(self, size: int = -1) -> str:
    assert self._is_valid, "MongoDB connection must be valid for retrieving data"

    self.logger.debug(
    f"Retrieving documents from {self._collection}. Expected size: \033[94m{self._collection.count_documents({})}\033[0m"
        )
    # modified line, to call unest_level for every entry coming out of self._collection.find()
    result = [{key: item for key, item in unest_level(data)}
              for data in self._collection.find()]

    self.logger.debug(
    f"Retrieved {len(result)} documents from remote. Size of json: {sum([len(document) for document in result])}"
        )
    return dumps(result)
```

Try to work around with something like that, this should unest more nested levels if they are dictionaries inside other dictionaries within your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I could not get it to work properly. Maybe I misunderstood something, but I ended up finding an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359783/how-to-flatten-multilevel-nested-json).

Out of curiosity, why did you use generators? Are they more performant than dicts?

Comment: They are many ways to work around, I used generators because I wanted a recursive function `unest_level` to work with multi nested dictionaries with an unknown depth and the generators allow me to iterate over it (no performance issue). In this case it would have been the same to use dictionaries an return the value unnested (at the end we create a list of dictionaries). If not for a normal case the iterators can help with memory issues or big data since the value is not compute until it is needed contrary to other objects as dictionaries. I think in general good to use Generators