# Flatten dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python

How can I flatten a dictionary of dictonaries in Python, and put them into a list? For example, say I have the following dict:

```
data = { id1 : {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}, id2 : {x: 4, y: 5, z: 6}}
```

How do I get:

```
[{id: id1, x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}, {id: id2, x: 4, y: 5, z: 6}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten nested Python dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

Comment: @Dillanm similar, but not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With python 3.5 and higher

```
>>> data = { 'id1' : {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, 'id2' : {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6}}
>>> [{**v, 'id':k} for k,v in data.items()]
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'id': 'id1'}, {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6, 'id': 'id2'}]
```

On older python versions

```
>>> [dict(v, id=k) for k,v in data.iteritems()]
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'id': 'id1'}, {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6, 'id': 'id2'}]
>>>
```

Comment: Should use `iteritems()` instead of `items()` for older versions.