# Flatten nested dictionary using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I would like to flatten a nested dictionary. A solution for such a problem was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41801708/8443371. Problem:
I would like to obtain a keys identical to the keys in the last layer only.
For an input:

```
d = {'a': 1,
     'c': {'b': {'x': 5,
                 'y' : 10}},
     'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

I would like to have an output:

```
{'a': 1, 'x': 5, 'y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Suggestions using python only should be probably slower than Pandas, which is based on a C implementation.

Note:
Assuming max two layer dictionary, I have a python solution, which seems to be very slow:

```
for key in dict.keys():
    if '.' in key:
       dict[key.split('.')[-1]] = dict.pop(key)
```

Comment: Doing it with pandas might be an overkill. Plus I don't know if there is a function for this case.

Comment: but pure python is slower, is not it?

Comment: You are most probably correct. timeit stats can back you up.

Comment: Have you tried implementing  it in pure python?

Comment: Yes. I can time it but I am pretty sure that it is slower...

Comment: In any case your examples tells me that it is not standard flattening. So you will have to write a parser.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution in pure python for the dictionary you've provided:

```
d = {'a': 1,
     'c': {'b': {'x': 5,
                 'y' : 10}},
     'd': [1, 2, 3]}

def flatten_dict(dic):
    result = {}
    for key in dic.keys():
        if isinstance(dic[key], dict):
            result.update(flatten_dict(dic[key]))
        else:
            result[key] = dic[key]
return result

flatten_dict(d)
{'a': 1, 'x': 5, 'y': 10, 'd': [1, 2, 3]}

%%timeit
flatten_dict(d)
2.45 µs ± 72.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```