# Flatten nested dictionaries with tuple keys

Tags: python, dictionary

How to generalize this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys) to the case keys that may be tuples?

As a benefit even in the case of all string keys, if these are accumulated to a tuple, there's no need for ad-hoc separators (though JSON export is another matter):

one approach is to base it on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19647596/1472770). I tried 2 versions:

```
def flatten_keys(d,handler,prefix=[]):
    return {handler(prefix,k) if prefix else k : v
        for kk, vv in d.items()
        for k, v in flatten_keys(vv, handler, kk).items()
        } if isinstance(d, dict) else { prefix : d }
```

where the tuple handlers are:

```
def tuple_handler_1(prefix,k):
    return tuple([prefix]+[k])

def tuple_handler_2(prefix,k):
    return tuple(flatten_container((prefix,k)))
```

Using the utility generator:

```
def flatten_container(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten_container(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i
```

Consider one of the test dict's but using a tuple key `('hgf',1)`:

```
data =  {'abc':123, ('hgf',1):{'gh':432, 'yu':433}, 'gfd':902, 'xzxzxz':{"432":{'0b0b0b':231}, "43234":1321}}
```

Neither works as intended:

```
flatten_keys(data,tuple_handler_1)
```

> {'abc': 123,  (('hgf', 1), 'gh'): 432,  (('hgf', 1), 'yu'): 433, 
>   'gfd': 902,  ('xzxzxz', ('432', '0b0b0b')): 231,  ('xzxzxz', '43234'):
>   1321}

`('xzxzxz', ('432', '0b0b0b'))`. is not flattened

And the 2nd flattens the input tuple key

```
flatten_keys(data,tuple_handler_2)
```

> {'abc': 123,  ('hgf', 1, 'gh'): 432,  ('hgf', 1, 'yu'): 433,  'gfd':
>   902,  ('xzxzxz', '432', '0b0b0b'): 231,  ('xzxzxz', '43234'): 1321}

Is there an obvious modification of the flatten method that will correctly join strings and other hashables?

**EDIT**

As per comments below, a problem handling key-clash with this method is inherent the base case of strings keys, eg `{'a_b':{'c':1}, 'a':{'b_c':2}}`.

Thus each key path should be a be tuple even in for `len` 1 key paths to avoid key clash eg  `{((1,2),): 3, (1,2):4}}`.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: what should the expected output look like for the given raw data?

Comment: deleted my answer. It looks like you're listing what not to do, but not giving us any indication of what you do want. (That last line is what I think would be correct.)

Comment: Do you want string keys or tuple keys?

Comment: @Ajax1234, flatten across levels, but preserve the type of input keys, in this case: `{'abc': 123, (('hgf', 1), 'gh'): 432, (('hgf', 1), 'yu'): 433, 'gfd': 902, ('xzxzxz', '432', '0b0b0b'): 231, ('xzxzxz', '43234'): 1321}`

Comment: @Jab, any combination of (hashable) key types.

Comment: @alancalvitti one problem (the consequence can be seen in Daniel's nice answer below) is that your desired output is "weird and unsafe".  It is inconsistent in not taking the top-level and converting it to a tuple, which can lead to all sorts of other corner cases.

Comment: @Cireo, can you give an example? I use this flatten operation routinely in another language with no problems for years (again modulo the JSON export issue hinted in my Q). The typical application is to generate flat tables/dataframes from hierarchical data.

Comment: Sure: how about `{(1,2): 3, 1: {2: 4}}`?  What output is desired?

Comment: @Cireo, the key-clash issue is inherent the base case using only strings as pointed out by ninjagecko `{'a_b':{'c':1}, 'a':{'b_c':2}}`. I think the obvious solution is for each key path to be a be tuple even in for len 1. In your example output should be `{((1,2),): 3, (1,2):4}}`. Will edit question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the following input/output

```
# input
{'abc': 123,
 ('hgf', 1): {'gh': 432, 'yu': 433},
 'gfd': 902,
 'xzxzxz': {'432': {'0b0b0b': 231}, '43234': 1321}}

# output
{('abc',): 123,
 (('hgf', 1), 'gh'): 432,
 (('hgf', 1), 'yu'): 433,
 ('gfd',): 902,
 ('xzxzxz', '432', '0b0b0b'): 231,
 ('xzxzxz', '43234'): 1321}
```

One approach is to recurse on your dictionary until you find a non-dictionary value and pass down the current key as a tuple during the recursion.

```py
def flatten_dict(deep_dict): 
    def do_flatten(deep_dict, current_key): 
        for key, value in deep_dict.items():
            # the key will be a flattened tuple
            # but the type of `key` is not touched
            new_key = current_key + (key,)
            # if we have a dict, we recurse
            if isinstance(value, dict): 
                yield from do_flatten(value, new_key) 
            else:
                yield (new_key, value) 
    return dict(do_flatten(deep_dict, ()))
```

Comment: I like this approach using generator, but can you modify to handle the updated Q, ie, in the case of `{(1,2): 3, 1: {2: 4}}, should output `{((1,2),): 3, (1,2):4}}` as per comment thread with Cireo. Your method outputs {(1, 2): 4}. In other words, key-paths of length 1 should be wrapped in a tuple to disambiguate.

Comment: I think the mod is as simple as: `entry_key = new_key if current_key else (key,)`

Comment: Thanks, - just saw your update - that's even nicer.