# I have a list which contains the route to a node in the json. How do access the node based on this route?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing

I have a list which contains data in the following format.

```
Data format: "1.3.4.2.1", "1.45.67.32.2", ...(the strings separated by dots 
can be of varying lengths)
```

This strings represent the route to the "status" node and the "last index" in the string represent the value that has to be assigned to the "@default" attribute in the status node.

I have a json of the following format.

```
json_tree = 
{
  "Gardens": {
    "Seaside": {
      "@loc": "porch",
      "@myID": "1.2.3",
      "Tid": "1",
      "InfoList": {
        "status": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "26"
        },
        "count": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "1"
        }
      },
      "BackYard": {
        "@loc": "backyard",
        "@myID": "75",
        "Tid": "2",
        "InfoList": {
          "status": {
            "@default": "6",
            "@myID": "32"
          },
          "count": {
            "@default": "0",
            "@myID": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, my route list contains the following information.

```
route_list = ["1.2.3.26.4","1.2.3.75.32.2",...] # this json_tree could have many more layers in the format shown above

Note: '1.2.3.26" is the route to the "status" node in "Gardens" and "4" is the value to be assigned to the "@default" node in the "status".
Note: '1.2.3.75.32" is the route to the "status" node in "BackYard" and "2" is the value to be assigned to the "@default" node in the "status".
```

As of now, I have the following method. I am unable to move further from here.

```
for item in route_list:
   UpdateJsonTree(json_tree, item)

def UdpateJsonTree(json_tree, item):
   # I am unsure on how to parse the json tree based on the route given
   # and update the '@default' value of the status node
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do your know how to simple acces an element? If the answer is yes iterate your information in reverse order key to key your_dict[k_n][k_n-1][...]

Comment: @Wonka I am not sure on how to do that. May you please assist me in it?

Comment: I cant find the element "1.2.3.26" in your dict, but example to acces -> json_tree["Gardens"]["Seaside"]. But Im not pretty sure to understund your problem and what you wanna do.

Comment: The "1.2.3" is the value of the "@myID" attribute in the "Seaside" node. The "26" is the value in the "@myID" attribute in the status node. The string "1.2.3.26" represents the route to the status node based on the values of the "@myID" attribute. Once I have found the "status" node based on the "1.2.3.26", then I need to assign the "@default" attribute the value of "4". I have given examples above in the text.

Comment: In `json_tree` should Seaside and BackYard be at the same level - if so you are missing a curly brace before the comma (,) before BackYard?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere The "backYard" is a nested node in the "Seaside". ```Note: '1.2.3.75.32" is the route based on the values of the "@myID" attribute to the "status" node in "BackYard" and "2" is the value to be assigned to the "@default" node in the "status".```

Comment: Then your result will be to update the Seaside status from `0` to `4` and update BackYard from `6` to `2`. Also, you want to drive the process based on the `route_list`?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Exactly, that is what I want to do and the value would be 2.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Any update? I have tried something like this as of now. It allows me to access the "@default" value for a given @myID" value.```def get_id(d, myid):
   if isinstance(d, dict) and d.get('@myID') == myid:
      yield {'@myID':d['@oid'], 'status':d['InfoList']['status']['@default']}
   for i in getattr(d, 'values', lambda :[])():
      yield from get_id(i, myid)```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Could you help me to figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere i am still unable to make any progress. Could you help?

Comment: Still working it. Trying the [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys) solution from the 179 point answer here to isolate the '@myID` occurrences, now looking into the back looping for the entire route. I'm slowly making progress.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere  ```def get_id(d, system, match):
    for k1, v1 in d.items():
        for k,v in v1.items():
            if k == system:
                return '{}{}.{}'.format(d['@myID'] + '.' if '@myID' in d else '',
                                            v['@myID'], v['InfoList']['status']['@myID'])
            else:
                for item in v:
                    if (item == system and (v['@myID'] + '.' + v[item]['@myID'] + '.' + v['InfoList']['status']['@myID']) == (match)):
         return(v['@myID'] + '.' + v[item]['@myID'] + '.' + v['InfoList']['status']['@myID'])```

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere thank you so much for the update. I tried sth like the one above. Still resolving the bugs in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197399/discussion-between-davestsomewhere-and-laura-smith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach starts by building a route master that includes a list entry for each route to check against (displayed at bottom).

Once the route master is available then the route check is straight forward.

`flatten` is from the 179 point answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Here's the code:

```py
import _collections_abc
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

l1 = [
    '1.2.3.26.4',
    '1.2.3.75.32.2'
]

json_tree = {
    "Gardens": {
        "Seaside": {
            "@loc": "porch",
            "@myID": "1.2.3",
            "Tid": "1",
            "InfoList": {
                "status": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "26"
                },
                "count": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "1"
                }
            },
            "BackYard": {
                "@loc": "backyard",
                "@myID": "75",
                "Tid": "2",
                "InfoList": {
                    "status": {
                        "@default": "6",
                        "@myID": "32"
                    },
                    "count": {
                        "@default": "0",
                        "@myID": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
    """Return flattened dict as list"""
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        if isinstance(v, _collections_abc.MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)


def add_id(path, id_value):
    """Update list of @myID paths"""
    id_list.append([path, id_value])


def update_json(path, value):
    """Update the json_data with the default value"""
    l_bracket_q = "['"
    r_bracket_q = "']"
    at_default = "['@default']"
    result = ''
    cmd = "json_tree"
    for key in path:
        cmd += l_bracket_q + key + r_bracket_q
    cmd += at_default
    cmd += ' = value'
    exec(cmd)


flat_list = flatten(json_tree)
id_list = []

#  Loop the flattened list filtering for ID's, excluding the ones in count
for k, v in [x for x in flat_list.items() if '@myID' in x[0] and 'count' not in x[0]]:
    add_id(k, v)

route_list = []

# start building the route list from the filtered id list
for id_entry in id_list:
    route_list.append(
        [[x for x in id_entry[0].split('_') if x != '@myID'],
         [y for y in id_entry[1].split('.')]])

route_master = []

#  generate the route master to include the path and the full route (as list not 1.2.3)
for id_entry in id_list:
    s1 = id_entry[0].split('_')
    tmp_route = []
    tmp_list = []
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i] == '@myID':
            break
        tmp_list.append(s1[i])
        for rte in route_list:
            if tmp_list == rte[0]:
                tmp_route.append(rte[1])
    route_item = list(itertools.chain(*tmp_route))
    tmp_list.append(route_item)
    route_master.append(tmp_list)

#  break out the default value from the route of the main driver file
l2 = list(zip(['.'.join(x.split('.')[:-1]) for x in l1], [x.split('.')[-1] for x in l1]))

#  loop the routes to process and update when found
for route, default in l2:
    for check_it in route_master:
        if route.split('.') == check_it[-1]:
            update_json(check_it[:-1], default)

#  print results
pprint(json_tree)
```

results:

```
{'Gardens': {'Seaside': {'@loc': 'porch',
                         '@myID': '1.2.3',
                         'BackYard': {'@loc': 'backyard',
                                      '@myID': '75',
                                      'InfoList': {'count': {'@default': '0',
                                                             '@myID': '2'},
                                                   'status': {'@default': '2',
                                                              '@myID': '32'}},
                                      'Tid': '2'},
                         'InfoList': {'count': {'@default': '0', '@myID': '1'},
                                      'status': {'@default': '4',
                                                 '@myID': '26'}},
                         'Tid': '1'}}}
```

Route Master:

```py
['Gardens', 'Seaside', ['1', '2', '3']]
['Gardens', 'Seaside', 'InfoList', 'status', ['1', '2', '3', '26']]
['Gardens', 'Seaside', 'BackYard', ['1', '2', '3', '75']]
['Gardens', 'Seaside', 'BackYard', 'InfoList', 'status', ['1', '2', '3', '75', '32']]
```

Comment: I had a quick question regarding your implementation, can we discuss in chat?

Comment: Sure thing - I opened the previous chat session clicking on the "Continue in chat" link above.