# How to reach a particular key value pair inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have json document as below. I would like to update all "points" to type integer. I'm familair with how to typecast. However I'm not able to reach to each indiviaul key/value pair inside the key "score". Would you please help me guide with the concept here

```
{"playerID": "123",
"score": [{"date": "1/1/2019", 
           "points": "10", 
            "somekey": "somevalue"
           }, 
           {"date": "1/1/2018", 
           "points": "100", 
            "somekey": "valuexyz"
           }]
}
```

I tried to read the json data into variable called "data"
data.get("score") returned a "list" of items
item(0) gets me entire record - date, points, somekey.
I'm not able to get to a specific key called points.

Should I onceagain convert my list to dictionary and then iterate to get to points? Isn't there any other way

```
data = {"playerID": "123",
"score": [{"date": "1/1/2019", 
       "points": "10", 
        "somekey": "somevalue"
       }, 
       {"date": "1/1/2018", 
       "points": "100", 
        "somekey": "valuexyz"
       }]
}
dlist = data.get("score") #returns list
```

Comment: See this for a discussion of how to flatten nested dicts, it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in data['score']:
    x['points'] = int(x['points'])
```