# flattening a dictionary containing a list of list and tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, flatten

```
from numpy import nan
d = {'E1': (((((['C', 'Me', 'Lans'], float(nan), ['3050', '55901']),
     float(nan)),
    float(nan)),
   ['2011-09-05 00:00:00', '3050-09-02 00:00:00']),
  ['2011-09-05 00:00:00', '3050-09-02 00:00:00']),
 'E2': (((((['Can', 'Mar', 'Horns'], ['26D']),
      ['1001', '14086']),
     float(nan),
    ['(100) 300-2345']),
   ['1001-09-02 00:00:00', '0100-09-02 00:00:00', '2011-19-26 00:00:00']),
  ['1001-09-02 00:00:00', '0100-09-02 00:00:00', '2011-19-26 00:00:00'])}
```

I have a messy looking dict `d`. I would like the following output where `d` is a list within a dictionary

```
d = {'E1': ['C', 'Me', 'Lans', float(nan),'3050', '55901', float(nan)), float(nan), '2011-09-05 00:00:00', '3050-09-02 00:00:00',
            '2011-09-05 00:00:00', '3050-09-02 00:00:00'],
     'E2': ['Can', 'Mar', 'Horns', '26D','1001', '14086', float(nan),'100 300-2345','1001-09-02 00:00:00', '0100-09-02 00:00:00', '2011-19-26 00:00:00',
             '1001-09-02 00:00:00', '0100-09-02 00:00:00', '2011-19-26 00:00:00']}
```

I've tried the code [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys) but it doesn't give me quite what I am looking for. Can any body help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function that recursively flattens lists and tuples:

```
def flatten(o):
    return [s for i in o for s in flatten(i)] if isinstance(o, (list, tuple)) else [o]
```

so that `{k: flatten(v) for k, v in d.items()}` returns:

```
{'E1': ['C',
        'Me',
        'Lans',
        nan,
        '3050',
        '55901',
        nan,
        nan,
        '2011-09-05 00:00:00',
        '3050-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-09-05 00:00:00',
        '3050-09-02 00:00:00'],
 'E2': ['Can',
        'Mar',
        'Horns',
        '26D',
        '1001',
        '14086',
        nan,
        '(100) 300-2345',
        '1001-09-02 00:00:00',
        '0100-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-19-26 00:00:00',
        '1001-09-02 00:00:00',
        '0100-09-02 00:00:00',
        '2011-19-26 00:00:00']}
```