# In Scrapy, how to use JSON loaded items to populate new fields?

Tags: python, json, scrapy, json-ld

I am trying to produce columns of data from the LD+JSON metadata found in the HTML of a jobs listings site. I've used scrapy Item Loaders to clean the HTML string and convert this metadata to a JSON object. I would then like to use the information contained within that JSON to populate further fields within my crawler.

Here is the spider so far, which crawls the most recent 100 jobs listing:

```py
import scrapy, json
from ..items import EthjobsScrapyItem, EthJobsLoader

class EthioJobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "EthioJobs"
    allowed_domains = ["ethiojobs.net"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.ethiojobs.net/latest-jobs-in-ethiopia/?searchId=1573067457.6526&action=search&page=1&listings_per_page=100&view=list"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for listing_url in response.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/section/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/table/tbody//@href').getall():
            yield response.follow(listing_url, callback=self.parse_listing)

    def parse_listing(self, response):
        loader = EthJobsLoader(item = EthjobsScrapyItem(), response=response)
        loader.add_xpath('JSON_LD', '//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()')

        yield loader.load_item()
```

where `items.py` is:

```py
import scrapy, re, json
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class EthjobsScrapyItem(scrapy.Item):
    JSON_LD     = scrapy.Field()
    datePosted  = scrapy.Field() # an example of a field that would populate data from the JSON data


def cleanJsonVar(self, jsonvar): # Clean HTML markup
    for TEXT in jsonvar:
        if jsonvar:
            try:
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"\r+|\n+|\t+|  |&nbsp;|amp;|</?.{,6}>", " ", TEXT).strip()
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"Job\sDescription", "", jsonvar)
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"\A\s+", "", jsonvar) 
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"( ){2,}", r" ", jsonvar)
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"\u2019", r" '", jsonvar)
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"\u25cf", r" -", jsonvar)
                jsonvar = re.sub(r"\\",r"/", jsonvar)

            except Exception as e:
                jsonvar = None
                print("ERROR: ", str(e))
        else:
            pass
        return jsonvar

def intoJsonVar(self, jsonvar): # Convert from string to JSON
    for TEXT in jsonvar: 
        return json.loads(TEXT)


class EthJobsLoader(ItemLoader):
    JSON_LD_in  =  cleanJsonVar
    JSON_LD_out =  intoJsonVar
```

`JSON_LD` is outputted from the crawler like so:

```
{'JSON_LD': ["{
    '@context': 'http://schema.org/',
    '@type': 'JobPosting',
    'title': 'Terms of Reference',
    'description': ' Terms of Reference for developing General Management Plan...,'
    'identifier': {
        '@type': 'PropertyValue',
        'name': 'Population Health and Environment â€“ Ethiopia Consortium (PHE EC)',
        'value': '65264'
    },
    'datePosted': '2019-12-10 04:13:31',
    'validThrough': '2019-12-20 23:59:59',
    'employmentType': 'Full Time',
    'hiringOrganization': {
        '@type': 'Organization',
        'name': 'Population Health and Envir...'
    },
    'jobLocation': {
        '@type': 'Place',
        'address': {
            '@type': 'PostalAddress',
            'addressLocality': 'ETH Region',
            'addressRegion': ' Addis Ababa ',
            'addressCountry': 'ETH'
        }
    }
}"]
}
```

My question is this: how would I take information from the above JSON and use it to populate new fields in my crawler?

Any and all input/critique is beyond welcome!

Answer (score 1):

First you'd probably want to flatten[1] your json ld file as `scrapy.Item` is expected to be flat or at least nest itself with other `scrapy.Items`. You also should get rid of private variables (the ones that being with @) as that's invalid character for variable names in python:

```
{
    '@context': 'http://schema.org/',
    '@type': 'JobPosting',
    'title': 'Terms of Reference',
    'description': ' Terms of Reference for developing General Management Plan...,'
    'identifier': {
        '@type': 'PropertyValue',
        'name': 'Population Health and Environment â€“ Ethiopia Consortium (PHE EC)',
        'value': '65264'
    }
```

to:

```
{
    'title': 'Terms of Reference',
    'description': ' Terms of Reference for developing General Management Plan...,'
    'identifier_name': 'Population Health and Environment â€“ Ethiopia Consortium (PHE EC)',
    'identifier_value': '65264'
    },
```

You'd have item:

```
class MyItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    description = Field()
    identifier_name = Field()
    identifier_value = Field()
```

Finally you can merge multiple items by simply recreating the item object with merged dictionary[2]:

```
first = MyItem()
first['title'] = 'foo'
json_ld = {
    'description': 'bar'
}
yield MyItem({**first, **json_ld})
# {'title': 'foo', 'description': 'bar'}
```

[1] There are many dictionary flattening functions and explanations available on stackoverflow, for example: [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys)
[2] `scrapy.Item` is just an extension of python dictionary so it can merge with any other python dictionary. For merging dictionaries see: [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive breakdown. I have added flattening to occur as an out processor, and the `JSON_LD` field is being crawled as so. However, I'm still unsure how to use that info to populate other fields in my crawler, especially considering the `JSON_LD` data needs to go through processing before it can be extracted. Would I need to create a new `parse` function somehow?

Comment: ideally you'd do everything in one `parse` callback. Pull json from page source -> flatten+clean it -> make `Item`; then parse html page source -> make `Item`; finally merge both items as decribed in my answer. If you're still stuck I can help you refactor your code to help you wrap your head around this if you pm me the details (you can find my contacts in my profile).