# How i can to move child dict to parent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict with child like this:

```
{
   "bookname" : "Harry Potter",
   "book_details" : {
         "amount" : 12,
         "price" : 1000,
   } 
}
```

I want to covert dict to below:

```
{
  "bookname" : "Harry Potter",
  "book_details_amount" :12,
  "book_details_price": 1000
}
```

Comment: As an aside, "child" is not really the correct terminology, it's a bit misleading. Anyway, have you tried anything at all? This seems like a rather straight-forward transformation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

Comment: @andreis11 Was previously marked as duplicate with that. I think those recursive solutions are too complicated for the OP's requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific dict, you can move `book_details` dict to the parent level like this:

```
d = {
   "bookname" : "Harry Potter",
   "book_details" : {
         "amount" : 12,
         "price" : 1000,
   } 
}

result = {"bookname": d["bookname"]}

for k, v in d["book_details"].items():
    result[f"book_details_{k}"] = v

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'bookname': 'Harry Potter', 'book_details_amount': 12, 'book_details_price': 1000}
```