# Breaking down nested dictionaries into dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe which in one of the columns have nested dictionaries.

```
df = {"Name": "XYZ", "Age": 42, 
     {"Place":{"KeyA": {"SubKey1": 0.2, "SubKey2": "value2"}}}
```

So my flat df is:

```
Name - Age - Place
XYZ - 42 - {"KeyA": {"SubKey-1": 0.2, "SubKey2": "value2"}}
```

I'm trying to break down the content of that column and transform it on multiple columns to end up with something like this:

```
Name - Age - KeyA-SubKey1 - KeyA-SubKey2
X - 42 - 0.2 - value2
```

But everything I was able to come up with so far ended up with `KeyError` or `Length of values does not match length of index`.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Convert the compound column to a Series, combine with the original DataFrame, and drop the original Place column:

```
df.join(df['Place'].apply(pd.Series)).drop('Place', axis1)
#     Name  Age  SubKey1 SubKey2
#KeyA  XYZ   42      0.2  value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [flatten dict method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027615/7964527)

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Place').map(flatten).tolist(),index=df.index))
Out[115]: 
  Name  Age  KeyA_SubKey-1 KeyA_SubKey2
0  XYZ   42            0.2       value2
```

```
import collections
    def flatten(d, parent_key='', sep='_'):
         items = []
         for k, v in d.items():
             new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
             if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
                 items.extend(flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
             else:
                 items.append((new_key, v))
         return dict(items)
```