# Basic pandas dataframe manipulation question

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following JSON snippet:

```
{'search_metadata': {'completed_in': 0.027,
                     'count': 2},
 'statuses': [{'contributors': None,
               'coordinates': None,
               'created_at': 'Wed Mar 31 19:25:16 +0000 2021',
               'text': 'The text',
               'truncated': True,
               'user': {'contributors_enabled': False,
                        'screen_name': 'abcde',
                        'verified': false
                        }
               }
               ,{...}]
}
```

The info that interests me is all in the `statuses` array. With pandas I can turn this into a DataFrame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Data['statuses'])
```

Then I extract a subset out of this dataframe with

```
dfsub = df[['created_at', 'text']]
```

`display(dfsub)` shows exactly what I expect.

But I also want to include `[user][screen_name]` to the subset.

```
dfs = df[[ 'user', 'created_at', 'text']]
```

is syntactically correct but `user` contains to much information.

How do I add only the `screen_name` to the subset?
I have tried things like the following but none of that works

```
[user][screen_name]
user.screen_name
user:screen_name
```

Comment: i'm curious. why did you use dataframe rather than json in the first place?

Comment: point of clarification: this is not a JSON snippet, but a `dict` (well, almost: the last "`false`" --in lowercase-- is not correct).

Comment: @Simon for being able to use the display function with its pretty output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normalize data before contructing DataFrame.
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41801708/14596032

Working example as an answer for your question:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(Data['statuses'], sep='_')
dfs = df[[ 'user_screen_name', 'created_at', 'text']]
print(dfs)
```

Comment: Totally agree, this is a much better way to put nested dicts into a `df`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html). The docs don't do justice to all the wonderful things `.str` can do, such as accessing `list` and `dict` items. Case in point, you can access `dict` elements like this:

```py
df['user'].str['screen_name']
```

That said, I agree with @VladimirGromes that a better way is to normalize your data into a flat table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access Dataframe, then Series, then Dict

```
df['user']                   # user column = Series
df['user'][0]                # 1st (only) item of the Series = dict
df['user'][0]['screen_name'] # screen_name in dict
```