# Accessing all elements within a list of dictionaries, and a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I hope everyone is having a good day.
I want to access the elements within a list of dictionaries, and a dictionary within a dictionary by using FOR LOOP. Or is there any other way to do this? I hope you can get me the idea. Thanks in advance.
The sample data is here:

```
listv = {'attached_volumes': [{'id': '1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c'}, {'id': 'c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d'}]}
```

The ids could be more than one.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys

Comment: ```
for k,v in listv.items():
    for d in v:
        d_id = d["id"]
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for a recursive solution.  If you add the output that you are trying to get from your example input that will help us give a more direct answer.