# explode dictionary keys in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to explode the keys in a Python dict such that if I have as input:

```
d = {"first": 
        {"second_a": 3, "second_b": 4},
     "another": 2,
     "anotherone": {"third_a": {"last": 3}}
     }
```

I will get as output a list of the exploded keys:

```
["first.second_a",
"first.second_b",
"another",
"anotherone.third_a.last"
]
```

Do you know any utility function that does this?

Thank you!

Comment: You have an unclosed quote btw

Comment: I doubt that there is a utility function that can do this, I assume that it won't be hard to make though

Comment: No, there are no utility functions, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: Is [this libary](https://github.com/ianlini/flatten-dict) what you're looking for?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dictionary contains only nested dictionaries you can do for example:

```py
d = {
    "first": {"second_a": 3, "second_b": 4},
    "another": 2,
    "anotherone": {"third_a": {"last": 3}},
}


def flatten(d, prefix=""):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from flatten(v, prefix + "." + k)
        else:
            yield (prefix + "." + k).strip(".")


print(list(flatten(d)))
```

Prints:

```py
['first.second_a', 
 'first.second_b', 
 'another', 
 'anotherone.third_a.last']
```

Comment: Your solution is also beautiful!