# how do I explode a nested dictionary for assignment iteration

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I have dictionaries I have to iterate like this:

```
for akey,bdict in cdict.items():
    for dkey,edict in bdict.items():
        for fkey,gdict in edict.items():
            for hkey,ival in gdict.items():
                # do something
```

How can I define `explode` so that I can do something like this with an arbitrarily large nested dict (I might need parentheses around some of the iterated items, but use of parentheses will be determined by `explode`, I would imagine)?

```
for akey,dkey,fkey,hkey,ival in explode(cdict):
    # do something

# or 

for *keys,val in explode(any_nesteddict):
    # do something
```

#### updated after answer from popcorndude on Jul 9 at 23:38

Is there a way to unpack to a certain level in the dictionary eg if I wanted to get `akey`, `dkey`, and `edict`?

```
for (akey,dkey),edict in explode(cdict, level=2):
    # do stuff

# which is different from original question:
for (akey,dkey,fkey,hkey),ival in explode(cdict):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

Answer (score 1):

```py
def explode(dct):
    # iterate over the top-level dictionary
    k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            # it's a nested dictionary, so recurse
            for ks, v2 in explode(v):
                # ks is a tuple of keys, and we want to
                # prepend k, so we convert it into a tuple
                yield (k,)+ks, v2
        else:
            # make sure that in the base case
            # we're still yielding the keys as a tuple
            yield (k,), v
```

We need to write `(k,)` rather than just `(k)`, because tuples in Python are defined by commas, and the parentheses are just for grouping, so `(k) == k`, but `(k,)` is a tuple containing `k`.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question with a follow up question