# Python - How to Convert complex JSON/Dict to single row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a need to take a complex json/dict object, and convert it in to a single row dataframe, with a column for each key/value pair. I would like each column header to describe the parent/child relationship from the original object, for example:

```json
{
   "fname":"Mickey",
   "lname":"Mouse",
   "Id":"12345",
   "education":[
      {
         "school":"acme University",
         "degree":"Doctor of Philosophy (PhD)"
      },
      {
         "school":"super university",
         "degree":"Master of Science (MS)"
      }
   ],
   "location":"New York, NY",
   "experience":[
      {
         "description":"I Work Hard",
         "title":"Manager",
         "work":"Hogwarts"
      },
      {
         "description":"I work Harder.",
         "title":"Senior Manager",
         "work":"hundred acre wood"
      }
   ],
   "startTime":4352,
   "endTime":234234
}
```

would become:

| fname | lname | Id | education.school1 | education.degree1 | education.school2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mickey | Mouse | 12345 | acme University | Doctor of Philosophy (PhD) | super university |

I have tried "json_normalize", but it only flattens the first level.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The example has open brackets. Could you please check and fix your example code, so the issue is reproducible? Thank you

Comment: Will probably have to flatten manually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys