# Unnest dictionary with nested Dictionary or list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

This question is related to [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys). I used that idea and modified to unnest list of dictionary but unable to do.

My input will be a dictionary which can have nested dictonaries or nested lists (list of dictionaries) as shown in the input to the function, flatten_dict_list

Below is my source code:

```
def flatten_dict_list(d, parent_key='', sep='.'):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        print("***")
        new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
        print(new_key)

        if isinstance(v, list):
          for z in v:
              if isinstance(z, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
                  print(type(z))
                  print(z)
                  items.extend(flatten_dict_list(z, new_key, sep=sep).items())
              else:
                  print(type(z))
                  print(z)
                  items.append((new_key, z))
        else:
          if isinstance(v, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
             print(type(v))
             print(v)
             items.extend(flatten_dict_list(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
          else:
             print(type(v))
             print(v)
             items.append((new_key, v))
    return dict(items)

print(flatten_dict_list({'a': 1, 'c': [{'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, {'test': 9999}, [{'s': 2}, {'t': 100}]], 'd': [1, 2, 3]}))
```

Expected output is:
{'a': 1, 'c.a': 2, 'c.b.x': 5, 'c.b.y': 10, 'c.test': 9999, 'c.s': 2, 'c.t': 100, 'd': 3}

My actual result is:
{'a': 1, 'c.a': 2, 'c.b.x': 5, 'c.b.y': 10, 'c.test': 9999, 'c': [{'s': 2}, {'t': 100}], 'd': 3}

Comment: If you flatten it like you want, and you get something like `{'a.b': 1, 'a.c': 2}` how would you know if the original was `{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}` or `{'a': [{'b': 1}, {'c': 2}]}`? Do you simply not care about the difference? Because it would appear those are very different data structures initially.

Comment: Correct, for my use case, I don't care about the difference. Reason is, the errors are logged in dictionary format, i.e., field_name: error code.

Comment: Can lists in your input contain anything other than `dict` values? For example `{'a': [1, 2]}` or `{'a': [{'b': 1}, 2]}`? And if so, how should such cases be dealt with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that:

- you don't care that both `{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}` and `{'a': [{'b': 1}, {'c': 2}]}` will map to the same `{'a.b': 1, 'a.c': 2}`
- there won't be anything other than dictionaries in the lists in the input data structure

This seems like a fairly clean solution:

```
def _compound_key_value(xs, prefix):
    if isinstance(xs, list):
        for x in xs:
            yield from _compound_key_value(x, prefix)
    elif isinstance(xs, dict):
        for k, v in xs.items():
            for p, r in _compound_key_value(v, prefix):
                yield prefix + (k,) + p, r
    else:
        yield prefix, xs


def flatten_dict_list(dl):
    return {'.'.join(k): v for k, v in _compound_key_value(dl, ())}


print(flatten_dict_list({'a': 1, 'c': [{'a': 2, 'b': {'x': 5, 'y' : 10}}, {'test': 9999}, [{'s': 2}, {'t': 100}]], 'd': [1, 2, 3]}))
```

Output

```
{'a': 1, 'c.a': 2, 'c.b.x': 5, 'c.b.y': 10, 'c.test': 9999, 'c.s': 2, 'c.t': 100, 'd': 3}
```

Note that it is recursive, like the solution you started out with, so I also assumed maximum recursion depth would not become an issue.

A few follow-up questions from the comments:

1. Difference between `yield` and `yield from`?
   `yield <value>` directly makes a generator yield that value. As you've probably read by now, when a value is requested from it, a generator runs until it has a value to yield, which it then yields and pauses, and continues running when the next value is needed, etc. `yield from <some other generator>` makes the generator request a value from another generator and it then immediately yields *that* value and it keeps yielding from it (one at a time) until there is nothing left, and  only then continues with the rest of the code, to the next `yield`.
   In the solution, `_compound_key_value(x, prefix)` starts a new generator recursively, which will start yielding values, which are yielded one by one using `yield from`. If the code had been `yield _compound_key_value(x, prefix)` (without the `from`), it would have yielded the generator itself, instead of values from it - that can be useful as well, but not here.
   The same could be achieved with `for a in _compound_key_value(x, prefix): yield a`, except that would be slower, because `yield from` has the new generator yield directly to the caller of this generator, without intermediate steps; and it is easier to read.
   TL;DR: `yield x` yields `x`, `yield from x` only works if `x` is a generator itself and yields everything from `x` one at a time.
2. Why are you passing an empty tuple as prefix?
   To avoid having to check if prefix has some value at all, it needs an initial value and I chose to pass the empty tuple instead of setting the default to the empty tuple in the signature like this:
   `def _compound_key_value(xs, prefix=()):`
   Either works, but I felt no default looked cleaner and since `_compound_key_value` is an internal function, not intended for direct use outside functions like `flatten_dict_list`, the requirement to pass  an empty tuple when calling it seemed reasonable.
   TL;DR: as a default, `prefix=()` would have also worked.
3. What is this doing? `(k, )`
   It is part of one statement: `yield prefix + (k,) + p, r` this yields a tuple of two values, the first being `prefix + (k,) + p`. `prefix` is the function parameter which expects a tuple, and `p` is also a tuple, since it's the first half of the tuple returned by the recursive call. If you add three tuples together, the result is a new tuple with all the parts combined in order, so `(k,)` takes a key as obtained from `xs.items()` and puts it in a tuple by itself, so it can be added together with the other tuples, and be yielded as a tuple, the first half of a tuple with `r` as the second half.
   TL;DR: `(k,)` makes a new tuple, with a single element `k`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It works elegantly. I spent quite a bit of time to understand the usage of Yield, functions starting with underscore, return statement with a one liner, joining,  etc. But I am still not understanding below. Can you please explain them to me ? 

1. Difference between yield and yield from ?
2. Why are you passing an empty tuple as prefix ?
3. What is this doing ?  (k, )

Comment: You're welcome, I've answered those three follow-up questions in an edit.