# converting dataclass to csv using dataclass-csv returns ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have the Property and Properties dataclasses and want to output into a csv format.
I took the references from https://pypi.org/project/dataclass-csv/ for csv writer.

```
@dataclass
class Property:
    property_id: str = field(default=None)
    property_features: dict[str, str] = field(default_factory=lambda: {
        'Property_1': None,
        'Property_2': None,
    })
@dataclass
class Properties:
    Property_list: list[Property] = field(default_factory=list)
```

output:

```
p_collection = Properties(Property_list=[Property(property_id='48a7bfa2', property_features={'Property_1': 'tin', 'Property_2': 'Electric blue'})])
```

To save the p_collection as csv, I tried:

```
from dataclass_csv import DataclassWriter
with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
   w = DataclassWriter(f, p_collection, Properties)
   w.write()
```

This errors with ValueError("Invalid 'data' argument. It must be a list")
Here Properties is a list of Property. Could you see if I am missing anything?

Comment: "Here Properties is a list of Property." False. `p_collection` is of type `Properties`.  The error message is telling you that you need to pass an argument of type `list`. It looks like replacing `p_collection` with `p_collection.Property_list` would work.  And probably the third argument would need to be `Property` not `Properties`.  Another option may be replacing `p_collection` with `[p_collection]`, but I'm not sure if `dataclass_csv` can handle nested dataclasses.

Comment: yeah. Thanks p_collection.Property_list fixes the error and still require property_features to convert as csv. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution using just Python global modules.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict, fields
import csv

@dataclass
class Property:
    property_id: str = field(default=None)
    property_features: dict[str, str] = field(default_factory=lambda: {
        'Property_1': None,
        'Property_2': None,
    })
@dataclass
class Properties:
    Property_list: list[Property] = field(default_factory=list)

p_collection = Properties(Property_list=[Property(property_id='48a7bfa2', property_features={'Property_1': 'tin', 'Property_2': 'Electric blue'})])

with open('dataclass_test.csv', 'w') as f:
   flds = [fld.name for fld in fields(Property)]
   w = csv.DictWriter(f, flds)
   w.writeheader()
   w.writerows([asdict(prop) for prop in p_collection.Property_list])

cat dataclass_test.csv
property_id,property_features
48a7bfa2,"{'Property_1': 'tin', 'Property_2': 'Electric blue'}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian.  How do you further convert the inner dict property_features to csv format

Comment: It produces the same output as the `DataclassWriter(f, p_collection.Property_list, Property)`. You will need to be more specific about "... convert the inner dict property_features to csv format"? CSV does not have nesting, so I am not sure what you are after? Add example of desired output **as update** to your question.

Comment: I unnested the property_features using reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794624/unnest-dictionary-with-nested-dictionary-or-list-of-dictionaries. This helped.
Is there a way to get the column names of the property_features as well?

Comment: example after unnest it looks like:
[{'property_id': '48a7bfa2', 'property_features.Property_1': 'tin', 'property_features.Property_2': 'Electric blue'},{}]

Comment: Per request in my comment **add the information** in your comments above as update to your question.  Including  the unnesting code you came up with and where you put it. Then folks don't have search comments for relevant information.

Comment: Without the code I can't be more specific, but it would seem you just need to end up with : `flds = ['property_id',  'property_features.Property_1',  'property_features.Property_2']`