# Flatten a tripled nested json into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested-json

### Problem

I was given a pretty big json file that looks like this minimal example:

```py
json_file = """
{
    "products":
    [

        {
            "id":"0",
            "name": "First",
            "emptylist":[],
            "properties" : 
            {
              "id" : "",
              "name" : ""
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"1",
            "name": "Second",
            "emptylist":[],
            "properties": 
            {
                "id" : "23",
                "name" : "a useful product",
                "features" :
                [
                    {
                        "name":"Features",
                        "id":"18",
                        "features":
                        [
                            {
                                "id":"1001",
                                "name":"Colour",
                                "value":"Black"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"2093",
                                "name":"Material",
                                "value":"Plastic"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Sizes",
                        "id":"34",
                        "features":
                        [
                            {
                                "id":"4736",
                                "name":"Length",
                                "value":"56"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"8745",
                                "name":"Width",
                                "value":"76"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id":"2",
            "name": "Third",
            "properties" : 
            {
                "id" : "876",
                "name" : "another one",
                "features" : 
                [
                    {
                        "name":"Box",
                        "id":"937",
                        "features":
                        [
                            {
                                "id":"3758",
                                "name":"Amount",
                                "value":"1"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"2222",
                                "name":"Packaging",
                                "value":"Blister"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"Features",
                        "id":"8473",
                        "features":
                        [
                            {
                                "id":"9372",
                                "name":"Colour",
                                "value":"White"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"9375",
                                "name":"Position",
                                "value":"A"
                            },
                            {
                                "id":"2654",
                                "name":"Amount",
                                "value":"6"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
"""
```

And I want to make a flat table out of it. It should look like this one:

```py
id    name   emptylist  properties.id properties.name    properties.features.name properties.features.id properties.features.features.id properties.features.features.name properties.features.features.value
0     First  []         ""            ""                 NaN                      NaN                    NaN                             NaN                               NaN                               
1     Second []         "23"          "a useful product" Features                 18                     1001                            Colour                            Black                             
1     Second []         "23"          "a useful product" Features                 18                     2093                            Material                          Plastic                           
1     Second []         "23"          "a useful product" Sizes                    34                     4736                            Length                            56                                
1     Second []         "23"          "a useful product" Sizes                    34                     8745                            Width                             76                                
2     Third             "876"         "another one"      Box                      937                    3758                            Amount                            1                                 
2     Third             "876"         "another one"      Box                      937                    2222                            Packaging                         Blister                           
2     Third             "876"         "another one"      Features                 8473                   9372                            Colour                            White                             
2     Third             "876"         "another one"      Features                 8473                   9375                            Position                          A                                 
2     Third             "876"         "another one"      Features                 8473                   2654                            Amount                            6
```

---

### What I tried

I tried this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

j = json.loads(json_file)
df = pd.json_normalize(j['products'])
df

  id    name emptylist properties.id   properties.name                                 properties.features  
0  0   First        []                                                                                 NaN  
1  1  Second        []            23  a useful product   [{'name': 'Features', 'id': '18', 'features': ...  
2  2   Third       NaN           876       another one   [{'name': 'Box', 'id': '937', 'features': [{'i...
```

And I tried to play a bit with the additional arguments, but I got nowhere. It seems like this is not the right way.

Can anyone help me?

---

### Additional infos

I got a working solution with R, but I need to be able to do it with Python.
If it helps, this would be the R code that I am trying to translate in Python.

```r
library(tidyr)
jsonlite::fromJSON(json_file)$products %>% 
  jsonlite::flatten() %>%
  unnest(properties.features         , names_sep = ".", keep_empty = TRUE) %>% 
  unnest(properties.features.features, names_sep = ".", keep_empty = TRUE)
```

---

### EDIT

With the help of @piterbarg and some research I got to this solution:

```py
j = json.loads(json_file)
df = pd.json_normalize(j['products'])
df1 = df.explode('properties.features')
df2 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True).drop('properties.features', axis = 1), 
                df1['properties.features'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix("properties.features.").drop("properties.features.0", axis = 1)], axis = 1)
df2 = df2.explode('properties.features.features')
df3 = pd.concat([df2.reset_index(drop=True).drop('properties.features.features', axis = 1), 
                df2['properties.features.features'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True).add_prefix("properties.features.features.").drop("properties.features.features.0", axis = 1)], axis = 1)
df3
```

With this I get exactly the solution I'm looking for but the code looks pretty messy and I'm not sure how efficient this solution may be. Any help?

Comment: You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027558/2476977) to be helpful

Comment: Wherever you have a list, you need to `explode` then do `json_normalize` again.

Comment: Hi Emma. Can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to what you have in Edit, but perhaps slightly shorter syntax and more performant.

If you have NaN in the DataFrame, older version of Pandas could fail on `json_normalize`.

This solution should work with Pandas 1.3+.

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(products)
df = df.explode('properties.features')
df = pd.concat([df.drop('properties.features', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True),
                pd.json_normalize(df['properties.features']).add_prefix('properties.features.')], axis=1)
df = df.explode('properties.features.features')
df = pd.concat([df.drop('properties.features.features', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True),
                pd.json_normalize(df['properties.features.features']).add_prefix('properties.features.features.')], axis=1)
```

Perf. with 1000 products.

```
Code in Edit : 4.85 s ± 218 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
This solution: 58.3 ms ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Great to hear it worked, and thank for the comment. I updated the answer to include the version info.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a repeated, if somewhat tedious, application of `explode` to expand lists and `apply(pd.Series)` to expand dicts:

```
df1 = df.explode('properties.features')
df2 = df1.join(df1['properties.features'].apply(pd.Series), lsuffix = '', rsuffix = '.properties.features').explode('features').drop(columns = 'properties.features')
df3 = df2.join(df2['features'].apply(pd.Series), lsuffix = '', rsuffix='.features').drop(columns = ['features','emptylist']).drop_duplicates()
```

`df3` looks like this:

```
      id  name    properties.id    properties.name      0    id.properties.features  name.properties.features      0.features    id.features  name.features    value
--  ----  ------  ---------------  -----------------  ---  ------------------------  --------------------------  ------------  -------------  ---------------  -------
 0     0  First                                       nan                       nan  nan                                  nan            nan  nan              nan
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        18  Features                             nan           1001  Colour           Black
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        18  Features                             nan           2093  Material         Plastic
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        18  Features                             nan           4736  Length           56
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        18  Features                             nan           8745  Width            76
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        34  Sizes                                nan           1001  Colour           Black
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        34  Sizes                                nan           2093  Material         Plastic
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        34  Sizes                                nan           4736  Length           56
 1     1  Second  23               a useful product   nan                        34  Sizes                                nan           8745  Width            76
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                       937  Box                                  nan           3758  Amount           1
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                       937  Box                                  nan           2222  Packaging        Blister
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                       937  Box                                  nan           9372  Colour           White
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                       937  Box                                  nan           9375  Position         A
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                       937  Box                                  nan           2654  Amount           6
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                      8473  Features                             nan           3758  Amount           1
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                      8473  Features                             nan           2222  Packaging        Blister
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                      8473  Features                             nan           9372  Colour           White
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                      8473  Features                             nan           9375  Position         A
 2     2  Third   876              another one        nan                      8473  Features                             nan           2654  Amount           6
```

The names are not quite like you want them, this could be fixed with `.rename(columns = {...})` if you want

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get as a result a 165rows X 12cols dataframe instead of 10x10 dataframe as per my expected output.

Comment: @Edo I edited my answer by adding `drop_duplicates` so it is down to 19 rows, they all seem to be distinct

Comment: I'm sorry @piterbarg, I'm aware that you're trying to hep me out here. And I thank you for it. But there are still some issues with your solution. With the original json I will end up having a dataset with 4mln rows: I can't use drop_duplicates. You still have 11 columns instead of 10. Also, some of the rows shouldn't exist: you put together features that are not originally together in the data. That would lead me to a massive data quality issue.

Comment: hey @piterbarg. Good news. With your code and some research I got to the solution I wanted. The code looks pretty ugly and I'm not sure it's a really "pythonian" code. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @Edo glad I was of some help!