# python flatten dict with leaving the same key name after flatten

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have the following dict:

```
{
"a": "b",
"c": {'d':'e', 'g':'f'}
}
```

and I want to flatten the dict, but in this way:

```
{
"a": "b",
'd':'e',
'g':'f'
}
```

You can assume there is no duplicate key.

I read about `flatten_dict` library but it looks there is no support in this.

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys)

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan the person specifically asks about skipping the parent keys, not compressing them

Answer (score 2):

For one level of nesting, a nice loop does the trick:

```py
result = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        result.update(value)  # add subdict directly into the dict
    else:
        result[key] = value  # non-subdict elements are just copied
```

If you have more nesting, the if/else should be executed recursively:

```py
def flatten(my_dict):
    result = {}
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            result.update(flatten(value))
        else:
            result[key] = value 
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys):

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def flatten(d):
    items = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, MutableMapping):
            items.extend(flatten(v).items())
        else:
            items.append((k, v))
    return dict(items)
```

```
>>> x = {
...     "a": "b",
...     "c": {'d': 'e', 'g': 'f'}
... }
>>> flatten(x)
{'a': 'b', 'd': 'e', 'g': 'f'}
```

This will work for all forms of any dictionary