# Format json or dictionary data in to partially flat structure in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, flatten

```
sample_data = {
  "instances": [
    {
      "a": "1987",
      "b": "2001",
      "art": {
        "009": {
          "art_id": "009",
          "mm": {
            "1002": {
              "mm_code": "1002",
              "node": {
                "6625583": {
                  "node_id": "6625583",
                  "node_sc": "186",
                  "node_si": [
                    {
                      "measure": "S",
                      "chest": 29
                    },
                    {
                      "measure": "M",
                      "chest": 32
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

what do we need?
I have sample_data and i need to convert `sample["instances"][0]` into following format

```
sample_data = {
  "instances": [
    {
      "a": "1987",
      "b": "2001",
      "art_id": "009",
      "mm_code": "1002",
      "node_id": "6625583",
      "node_sc": "186",
      "measure": "S",
      "chest": 29
    },
    { 
      "a": "1987",
      "b": "2001",
      "art_id": "009",
      "mm_code": "1002",
      "node_id": "6625583",
      "node_sc": "186",
      "measure": "M",
      "chest": 32
    }
  ]
}
```

requirements

1. Need a very less time-consuming solution
2. Multiple "art_id" s or "art"  and "mm" nested values are also possible. This means that :

```
{ "instances":
  [
    { "a": "1987", "b": "2001",
      "art":
         {
         001:{--},
         002:{--}
          }
    },
   { "a": "197", "b": "201",
      "art":
         {
         001:{--},
         002:{--}
          }
    },
 ]
}
```

And this applies to `mm` and `nodes` as well

tried this solution :
[imran's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys) but could not reach the required format.
Thank you for all the help incoming

Comment: If you change it in that way then you are changing the structure of the data, which may mean that any code that processes it will not find the items it expects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution how you can flatten this dictionary:

```py
sample_data = {
    "instances": [
        {
            "a": "1987",
            "b": "2001",
            "art": {
                "009": {
                    "art_id": "009",
                    "mm": {
                        "1002": {
                            "mm_code": "1002",
                            "node": {
                                "6625583": {
                                    "node_id": "6625583",
                                    "node_sc": "186",
                                    "node_si": [
                                        {"measure": "S", "chest": 29},
                                        {"measure": "M", "chest": 32},
                                    ],
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
        }
    ]
}


def find_node_si(dct):
    if "node_si" not in dct:
        next_dct = next(v for v in dct.values() if isinstance(v, dict))
        return find_node_si(next_dct)
    else:
        return dct["node_si"]


def return_all_key_values(dct):
    keys = [(k, v) for k, v in dct.items() if not isinstance(v, (list, dict))]
    next_dct = next((v for v in dct.values() if isinstance(v, dict)), None)
    if next_dct:
        return keys + return_all_key_values(next_dct)
    else:
        return keys


out = {"instances": []}
for i in sample_data["instances"]:
    dct = return_all_key_values(i)
    for node_si in find_node_si(i):
        out["instances"].append(dict(dct + list(node_si.items())))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "instances": [
        {
            "a": "1987",
            "b": "2001",
            "art_id": "009",
            "mm_code": "1002",
            "node_id": "6625583",
            "node_sc": "186",
            "measure": "S",
            "chest": 29,
        },
        {
            "a": "1987",
            "b": "2001",
            "art_id": "009",
            "mm_code": "1002",
            "node_id": "6625583",
            "node_sc": "186",
            "measure": "M",
            "chest": 32,
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Andrej https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely  , the solution works for the given input. Thank you! But I mentioned as point 2, it can have many keys in each nested dictionary. I can't edit the input with all possibilities due to the limitations of the question format. But I have edited the question a bit to be more clear. I hope that helps –